# how to post data From angular js to zend controller?

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

view page:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<form name="login_form" ng-submit="submit()" >
    Email: <input type="email" ng-model="login.email" required/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" ng-model="login.pass" required/><br />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

main.js

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.login = {};
$scope.submit = function(){

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login',
        data: $scope.login,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    }).
        success(function(response) {
            window.location.href = "/login";
        }).
        error(function(response) {
            $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
        });
}
```

LoginController:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));}
```

i need to fetch data from angular form and pass it to zend controller and perform login check and submit form.Could anybody help with step by step explanation?

Comment: To be a valid HTTP POST, don't you need to have a HTML name attached to the JSON submission? 

In the login controller, add `error_log( file_get_contents("php://input") );`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tutoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your main.js like this;

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.login = {email: "", password: ""};
$scope.login = $.param($scope.login);
$scope.submit = function(){

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login',
        data: $scope.login,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    }).
        success(function(response) {
            window.location.href = "/login";
        }).
        error(function(response) {
            $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
        });
}
```

In your php file access your email and password like;

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
```

and send these credentials to your zend controller. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found another post that talks about angular not sending data in a manner that php expects. Namely it is doing a json encoding. When I ran into this issue, the REQUEST was empty. Check out the following post:

[AngularJs http post does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)