# AngularJs $http.post() does not send data

Tags: angularjs, post, angular-http

Could anyone tell me why the following statement does not send the post data to the designated url? The url is called but on the server when I print $_POST - I get an empty array. If I print message in the console before adding it to the data - it shows the correct content.

```
$http.post('request-url',  { 'message' : message });
```

I've also tried it with the data as string (with the same outcome):

```
$http.post('request-url',  "message=" + message);
```

It seem to be working when I use it in the following format:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'request-url',
    data: "message=" + message,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

but is there a way of doing it with the $http.post() - and do I always have to include the header in order for it to work? I believe that the above content type is specifying format of the sent data, but can I send it as javascript object?

Comment: Is the url in the same origin?

Comment: Sorry - yes for all examples it's the same url

Comment: @SpencerMark sorry.. i tried above your working code.. its not working for me.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

I had the same problem using asp.net MVC and [found the solution here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312032007/http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/)

> There is much confusion among newcomers to **AngularJS** as to why the
> `$http` service shorthand functions (`$http.post()`, etc.) don’t appear to
> be swappable with the **jQuery** equivalents (`jQuery.post()`, etc.)
>
> The difference is in how **jQuery** and **AngularJS** serialize and transmit the data. Fundamentally, the problem lies with your server language of choice being unable to understand AngularJS’s transmission natively ... By default, **jQuery** transmits data using

```
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
```

> and the familiar `foo=bar&baz=moe` serialization.

**AngularJS**, however, transmits data using

> 

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

> and `{ "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" }`

> JSON serialization, which unfortunately some Web server languages—*notably
> PHP*—do not unserialize natively.

Works like a charm.

**CODE**

```
// Your app's root module...
angular.module('MyModule', [], function($httpProvider) {
  // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
 
  /**
   * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
   * @param {Object} obj
   * @return {String}
   */ 
  var param = function(obj) {
    var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
      
    for(name in obj) {
      value = obj[name];
        
      if(value instanceof Array) {
        for(i=0; i<value.length; ++i) {
          subValue = value[i];
          fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
          innerObj = {};
          innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
          query += param(innerObj) + '&';
        }
      }
      else if(value instanceof Object) {
        for(subName in value) {
          subValue = value[subName];
          fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
          innerObj = {};
          innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
          query += param(innerObj) + '&';
        }
      }
      else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
        query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
    }
      
    return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
  };
 
  // Override $http service's default transformRequest
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {
    return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
  }];
});
```

Comment: I have add'd this script to bower, use `bower install angular-post-fix --save-dev` to add it.

Comment: so is there a way to change php's transmits data method. Because that is the issue I am having currently.

Comment: This code works great on the most part, but I've had issues with it when submitting a hierarchy of empty objects or even flat empty values. For example, { a: 1, b: { c: { d: { } } }, e: undefined, f: null, g: 2 } will not be encoded properly, and PHP will get it as [ "a" => "1", "g" => "2" ]. The entire structure under "b", as well as "e" and "f", including the keys themselves - would be lost. I posted alternative code below, with which the above structure gets decoded as: [ "a" => "1",  "b" => [ "c" => [ "d" => "" ] ], "e" => "", "f" => "", "g" => "2" ].

Comment: how should i implement this for multipart/form-data?

Comment: Superb :) Indeed worked like a charm. I faced the issue with Spring MVC

Comment: @obe this skips empty array also

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650148/1225328) is a modernized version of this code.

Comment: Still I assume the client won't be able to know which form the server is understanding the message. whether its Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded or Content-Type: application/json

Comment: **Content-Type: application/json**  this is work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 116):

It's not super clear above, but if you are receiving the request in PHP you can use:

`$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);`

To access an array in PHP from an AngularJS POST.

Comment: I needed to add true to force it to an array when overwriting the $_POST array with it. ```json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);```

Comment: @Zalaboza, I would agree that it is tough to have any solution considered 'universal' but I don't agree that it is 'hacky'--- php.net states: "file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance." Granted we're not reading a file in this situation but we are nonetheless reading posted json data. It would be great if you could contribute a new answer or provide new information to help readers (including myself) make a better decision about this.

Answer (score 78):

You can set the default "Content-Type" like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

About the `data` format:

> The $http.post and $http.put methods accept any JavaScript object (or a string) value as their data parameter. If data is a JavaScript object it will be, by default, converted to a JSON string.

Try to use this variation

```
function sendData($scope) {
    $http({
        url: 'request-url',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'message' : message }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've just tried the variation with the data as string and : headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} - and that seem to work, but is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Set default content type as described above and for data don't use js object. Use string like this: 'message='+message
Works for me

Answer (score 62):

I have had a similar issue, and I wonder if this can be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443066

```
var xsrf = $.param({fkey: "key"});
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: xsrf,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Regards,

Comment: It looks like the headers was the only change we needed. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me :)  
The problem was the encoding of the POST data.

Answer (score 34):

I like to use a function to convert objects to post params.

```
myobject = {'one':'1','two':'2','three':'3'}

Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
    var p = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
    }
    return p.join('&');
};

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: Object.toparams(myobject),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Answer (score 30):

This has finally been addressed in angular 1.4 using **$httpParamSerializerJQLike**

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6039

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseUrl,
  data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
    "user":{
      "email":"wahxxx@gmail.com",
      "password":"123456"
    }
  }),
  headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
})})
```

Comment: I am facing issue POST http://192.168.225.75:7788/procure/p/search 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 20):

I use [jQuery param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) with [AngularJS post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) requrest. Here is a example ... create AngularJS application module, where `myapp` is defined with `ng-app` in your HTML code.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

Now let us create a Login controller and POST email and password.

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    // default post header
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    // send login data
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://example.com/user/login',
        data: $.param({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle success things
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle error things
    });
}]);
```

I don't like to exaplain the code, it is simple enough to understand :) Note that `param` is from jQuery, so you must install both jQuery and AngularJS to make it working. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with AngularJS and Node.js + Express 4 + Router

Router expects the data from post's request in body. This body was always empty if i followed the example from Angular Docs

Notation 1

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'})
```

But if i used it in the data

Notation 2

```
$http({
       withCredentials: false,
       method: 'post',
       url: yourUrl,
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
       data: postData
 });
```

Edit 1:

Otherwise node.js router will expect the data in req.body if used notation 1:

```
req.body.msg
```

Which also sends the information as JSON payload. This is better in some cases where you have arrays in your json and x-www-form-urlencoded will give some problems.

it worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

Unlike JQuery and for the sake of pedantry, Angular uses JSON format for POST 
data *transfer* from a client to the server (JQuery applies x-www-form-urlencoded presumably, although JQuery and Angular uses JSON for data imput). Therefore there are two parts of problem: in js client part and in your server part. So you need:

1. put js Angular client part like this:

   ```
   $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'request-url',
   data: {'message': 'Hello world'}
   });
   ```

**AND**

2. write in your server part to receive data from a client (if it is php).

   ```
           $data               = file_get_contents("php://input");
           $dataJsonDecode     = json_decode($data);
           $message            = $dataJsonDecode->message;
           echo $message;     //'Hello world'
   ```

Note: $_POST will not work!

The solution works for me fine, hopefully, and for you.

Answer (score 8):

To build on @felipe-miosso's answer:

1. Download it as an AngularJS module from [here](https://gist.github.com/thinkadoo/9362570/raw/92c2fffb396a2c1e4a85becb094fe87ab18d0efc/angular-post-fix.js),
2. Install it
3. Add it to your application:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('my_app', [ ... , 'httpPostFix']);
   ```

Answer (score 8):

To send data via Post methode with `$http` of angularjs you need to change

`data: "message=" + message`, with  `data: $.param({message:message})`

Comment: why is data: $.param required when sending AngularJS post data ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but in response/addition to Don F's answer:

`$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

A second parameter of `true` needs to be added to the `json_decode` function in order to properly return an associative array:

`$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Answer (score 6):

Angular

```
  var payload = $.param({ jobId: 2 });

                this.$http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'web/api/ResourceAction/processfile',
                    data: payload,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                });
```

WebAPI 2

```
public class AcceptJobParams
        {
            public int jobId { get; set; }
        }

        public IHttpActionResult ProcessFile([FromBody]AcceptJobParams thing)
        {
            // do something with fileName parameter

            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

This code solved the issue for me. It is an application-level solution:

```
moduleName.config(['$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function(data) {
        var requestStr;
        if (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var key in data) {
                if (requestStr) {
                    requestStr += "&" + key + "=" + data[key];
                } else {
                    requestStr = key + "=" + data[key];
                }
            }
        }
        return requestStr;
    });
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your js file:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

and add this to your server file:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I resolve the problem like this :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myUri', 
    data: $.param({ param1: 'blablabla', param2: JSON.stringify(objJSON) }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(
    function(res) {
        console.log('succes !', res.data);
        deferred.resolve(res.data);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('error...', err);
        deferred.resolve(err);
    }
);
return deferred.promise;
```

You need to use JSON.stringify for each param containing a JSON object, and then build your data object with "$.param" :-)

NB : My "objJSON" is a JSON object containing array, integer, string and html content. His total size is >3500 characters.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced similar problem and i was doing something like this and that didn't worked. My Spring controller was not able read data parameter.

```
var paramsVal={data:'"id":"1"'};
  $http.post("Request URL",  {params: paramsVal});
```

But reading this forum and API Doc, I tried following  way and that worked for me.
If some one also have similar problem, You can try below way as well.

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "Request URL",           
      params: paramsVal,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
            });
```

Please check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post  for what param config does.
{data:'"id":"1"'} – Map of strings or objects which will be turned to URL?data="id:1"

Answer (score 4):

this is probably a late answer but i think the most proper way is to use the same piece of code angular use when doing a "get" request using you `$httpParamSerializer` will have to inject it to your controller 
so you can simply do the following without having to use Jquery at all ,
`$http.post(url,$httpParamSerializer({param:val}))`

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializer){
    $http.post(url,$httpParamSerializer({param:val,secondParam:secondVal}));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the OP's suggested working format & Denison's answer, except using `$http.post` instead of just `$http` and is still dependent on jQuery.

The good thing about using jQuery here is that complex objects get passed properly; against manually converting into URL parameters which may garble the data.

```
$http.post( 'request-url', jQuery.param( { 'message': message } ), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know has ***accepted*** answer. But, following might help to future readers, if the answer doesn't suit them for any reason.

Angular doesn't do ajax same as jQuery. While I tried to follow the guide to modify angular `$httpprovider` , I encountered other problems. E.g. I use codeigniter in which `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` function always failed (which was written by another programmer and used globally, so cant change) saying this was not real ajax request.

To solve it, I took help of [deferred promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred).  I tested it in Firefox, and ie9 and it worked.

I have following function defined ***outside*** any of the angular code. This function makes regular jquery ajax call and returns deferred/promise (I'm still learning) object.

```
function getjQueryAjax(url, obj){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        data: obj
    });
}
```

Then I'm calling it angular code using the following code. Please note that we have to update the `$scope` manually using `$scope.$apply()` .

```
    var data = {
        media: "video",
        scope: "movies"
    };
    var rPromise = getjQueryAjax("myController/getMeTypes" , data);
    rPromise.success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.testData = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log($scope.testData);
        });
    }).error(function(){
        console.log("AJAX failed!");
    });
```

---

This may not be the perfect answer, but it allowed me to use jquery ajax calls with angular and allowed me to update the `$scope`.

Comment: Angular has it own promises service called $q since 1.3. No need to use JQuery for a post.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in express .. to resolve you have to use bodyparser to parse json objects before sending http requests ..

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am using asp.net WCF webservices with angular js and below code
>   worked:

```
 $http({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//required
        method: "POST",
        url: '../../operation/Service.svc/user_forget',
        dataType: "json",//optional
        data:{ "uid_or_phone": $scope.forgettel, "user_email": $scope.forgetemail },
        async: "isAsync"//optional

       }).success( function (response) {

         $scope.userforgeterror = response.d;                    
       })
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't find a complete code snippet of how to use $http.post method to send data to the server and why it was not working in this case.

Explanations of below code snippet...

1. I am using jQuery $.param function to serialize the JSON data to www post data
2. Setting the Content-Type in the config variable that will be passed along with the request of angularJS $http.post that instruct the server that we are sending data in www post format.
3. Notice the $htttp.post method, where I am sending 1st parameter as url,  2nd parameter as data (serialized) and 3rd parameter as config.

Remaining code is self understood.

```
$scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                fName: $scope.firstName,
                lName: $scope.lastName
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post('/ServerRequest/PostDataResponse', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + header +
                    "<hr />config: " + config;
            });
        };
```

Look at the code example of [$http.post method here](http://techfunda.com/Examples/Show/565).

Answer (score 3):

If your using PHP this is a easy way to access an array in PHP from an AngularJS POST.

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

Comment: [This article may help](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/12/how-to-handle-json-post-request-using-php/) people.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the data you want to send as second parameter:

```
$http.post('request-url',  message);
```

Another form which also works is:

```
$http.post('request-url',  { params: { paramName: value } });
```

Make sure that `paramName` exactly matches the name of the parameter of the function you are calling.

Source: [AngularJS post shortcut method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: Can anybody explain why this answer has been voted down?

Comment: There is no way that this solution is voted down, it's the simplest, shortest and proven in angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 3):

If using **Angular >= 1.4**, here's the cleanest solution using [the serializer provided by Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike):

```
angular.module('yourModule')
  .config(function ($httpProvider, $httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift($httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider.$get());
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
});
```

And then you can simply do this anywhere in your app:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/requesturl',
  data: {
    param1: 'value1',
    param2: 'value2'
  }
});
```

And it will correctly serialize the data as `param1=value1&param2=value2` and send it to `/requesturl` with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` Content-Type header as it's normally expected with POST requests on endpoints.

**TL;DR**

During my research I found that the answer to this problem comes in many different flavors; some are very convoluted and depend on custom functions, some depend on jQuery and and some are incomplete in suggesting that you only need to set the header.

If you just set the `Content-Type` header, the end point will see the POST data, but it won't be in the standard format because unless you provide a string as your `data`, or manually serialize your data object, it will all be serialized as JSON by default and may be incorrectly interpreted at the endpoint.

e.g. if the correct serializer was not set in the above example, it would be seen in the endpoint as:

```
{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}
```

And that can lead to unexpected parsing, e.g. ASP.NET treats it as a `null` parameter name, with `{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}` as value; or Fiddler interprets it the other way, with `{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}` as the parameter name, and `null` as the value.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem the parameter I was posting turned out to be an array of objects instead of a simple object.

Answer (score 2):

Just updated from angular 1.2 to 1.3, have found a problem in the code. Transforming a resource will lead to an endless-loop because (I think) of the $promise holding again the same object. Maybe it will help someone...

I could fix that by:

```
[...]
  /**
 * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @return {String}
 */
var param = function (obj) {
var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

angular.forEach(obj, function(value, name) {
+    if(name.indexOf("$promise") != -1) {
+        return;
+    }

    value = obj[name];
    if (value instanceof Array) {
        for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the accepted answer's code (Felipe's code) for a while and it's been working great (thanks, Felipe!).

However, recently I discovered that it has issues with empty objects or arrays.
For example, when submitting this object:

```
{
    A: 1,
    B: {
        a: [ ],
    },
    C: [ ],
    D: "2"
}
```

PHP doesn't seem to see B and C at all. It gets this:

```
[
    "A" => "1",
    "B" => "2"
]
```

A look at the actual request in Chrome shows this:

```
A: 1
:
D: 2
```

I wrote an alternative code snippet. It seems to work well with my use-cases but I haven't tested it extensively so use with caution.

I used TypeScript because I like strong typing but it would be easy to convert to pure JS:

```
angular.module("MyModule").config([ "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) {
    // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";

    function phpize(obj: Object | any[], depth: number = 1): string[] {
        var arr: string[] = [ ];
        angular.forEach(obj, (value: any, key: string) => {
            if (angular.isObject(value) || angular.isArray(value)) {
                var arrInner: string[] = phpize(value, depth + 1);
                var tmpKey: string;
                var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
                if (depth == 1) tmpKey = encodedKey;
                else tmpKey = `[${encodedKey}]`;
                if (arrInner.length == 0) {
                    arr.push(`${tmpKey}=`);
                }
                else {
                    arr = arr.concat(arrInner.map(inner => `${tmpKey}${inner}`));
                }
            }
            else {
                var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
                var encodedValue;
                if (angular.isUndefined(value) || value === null) encodedValue = "";
                else encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(value);

                if (depth == 1) {
                    arr.push(`${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`);
                }
                else {
                    arr.push(`[${encodedKey}]=${encodedValue}`);
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    // Override $http service's default transformRequest
    (<any>$httpProvider.defaults).transformRequest = [ function(data: any) {
        if (!angular.isObject(data) || data.toString() == "[object File]") return data;
        return phpize(data).join("&");
    } ];
} ]);
```

It's less efficient than Felipe's code but I don't think it matters much since it should be immediate compared to the overall overhead of the HTTP request itself.

Now PHP shows:

```
[
    "A" => "1",
    "B" => [
        "a" => ""
    ],
    "C" => "",
    "D" => "2"
]
```

As far as I know it's not possible to get PHP to recognize that B.a and C are empty arrays, but at least the keys appear, which is important when there's code that relies on the a certain structure even when its essentially empty inside.

Also note that it converts *undefined*s and *null*s to empty strings.

Comment: TypeScript the best way to code in POO with JavaScript !

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by below codes:

Client Side (Js):

```
     $http({
                url: me.serverPath,
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            }).
                success(function (serverData) {
                    console.log("ServerData:", serverData);
    ......
```

notice that data is an object.

On the server (ASP.NET MVC):

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
        public string Api()
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AgentRequest>(Request.Form[0]);
            if (data == null) return "Null Request";
            var bl = Page.Bl = new Core(this);

            return data.methodName;
        }
```

and 'AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute' is needed for cross domain requests:

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not angular's fault. Angular is designed to work in JSON world. So when $http service send AJAX request, it send all your data as a payload, not as form-data so that your backend application can handle it. But jQuery does some things internally. You instruct jQuery's $ajax module to bind form-data as JSON but before sending AJAX request, it serialized JSON and add `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. This way your backend application able to received form-data in form of post parameters and not JSON.

But you can modify angular $http service's default behavior by

1. Adding header
2. Serializing json

$httpParamSerializerJQLike is angular's in-built service which serializes json in the same way $.param does of jQuery.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'request-url',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(json-form-data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
    }
});
```

If you need a plugin to serialize form-data into JSON first, use this one https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

Comment: when I tried with, $http.put('/api/', {name:1}). it's sending with serialized json data. but for POST, I need to set header and serialize the data as you said. do you know why PUT doesn't need that, but only POST need?

Comment: That's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

use this way. no need to write so much

```
 isAuth = $http.post("Yr URL", {username: username, password: password});
```

and in the nodejs back end

```
app.post("Yr URL",function(req,resp)
{

  var username = req.body.username||req.param('username');
  var password = req.body.password||req.param('password');
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small **PHP helper function** that allows both types of input parameters :

```
function getArgs () {
    if ($input = file_get_contents('php://input') && $input_params = json_decode($input,true))
        return $input_params + $_POST + $_GET;
    return $_POST + $_GET;
}
```

Usage :

```
<?php
    include("util.php"); # above code
    $request = getArgs();

    $myVar = "";
    if (isset($request['myVar']))
        $myVar = $request['myVar'];
?>
```

Therefore no changes required to your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

By using very simple method, we can follow this:

```
 $http({
        url : "submit_form_adv.php",
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+' = '+encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));

            return str.join('&');
        },
        data : {sample_id : 100, sample_name: 'Abin John'},

    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    }).error(function(ata, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the simple solution on

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/04/18/post-a-simple-string-value-from-angularjs-to-net-web-api

```
return $http.post(Config.apiUrl + '/example/processfile', '"' + fileName + '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just proposing a modernized version of [@FelipeMiosso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276775/1225328):

```js
.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {

  function buildKey(parentKey, subKey) {
    return parentKey + "[" + subKey + "]";
  }

  function buildObject(key, value) {
    var object = {};
    object[key] = value;
    return object;
  }

  function join(array) {
    return array.filter(function (entry) {
      return entry;
    }).join("&");
  }

  function arrayToQueryString(parentKey, array) {
    return join(array.map(function (value, subKey) {
      return toQueryString(buildObject(buildKey(parentKey, subKey), value));
    }));
  }

  function objectToQueryString(parentKey, object) {
    return join(Object.keys(object).map(function (subKey) {
      return toQueryString(buildObject(buildKey(parentKey, subKey), object[subKey]));
    }));
  }

  function toQueryString(input) {
    return join(Object.keys(input).map(function (key) {
      var value = input[key];
      if (value instanceof Array) {
        return arrayToQueryString(key, value);
      } else if (value instanceof Object) {
        return objectToQueryString(key, value);
      } else if (undefined !== value && null !== value) {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    }));
  }

  function isQueryStringEligible(input) {
    return null !== input && "object" === typeof input && "[object File]" !== String(input);
  }

  var interceptor = [function () {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        if (0 <= ["post", "put", "patch"].indexOf(config.method.toLowerCase()) && isQueryStringEligible(config.data)) {
          config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
          config.data = toQueryString(config.data);
        }
        return config;
      }
    };
  }];

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);

}])
```

ES6 version:

```js
.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {

  "use strict";

  const buildKey = (parentKey, subKey) => `${parentKey}[${subKey}]`;

  const buildObject = (key, value) => ({ [key]: value });

  const join = (array) => array.filter((entry) => entry).join("&");

  const arrayToQueryString = (parentKey, array) =>
    join(array.map((value, subKey) =>
      toQueryString(buildObject(buildKey(parentKey, subKey), value))));

  const objectToQueryString = (parentKey, object) =>
    join(Object.keys(object).map((subKey) =>
      toQueryString(buildObject(buildKey(parentKey, subKey), object[subKey]))));

  const toQueryString = (input) => join(Object.keys(input).map((key) => {
    const value = input[key];
    if (value instanceof Array) {
      return arrayToQueryString(key, value);
    } else if (value instanceof Object) {
      return objectToQueryString(key, value);
    } else if (undefined !== value && null !== value) {
      return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }));

  const isQueryStringEligible = (input) =>
    null !== input && "object" === typeof input && "[object File]" !== String(input);

  const interceptor = [() => ({
    request(config) {
      if (0 <= ["post", "put", "patch"].indexOf(config.method.toLowerCase()) && isQueryStringEligible(config.data)) {
        config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
        config.data = toQueryString(config.data);
      }
      return config;
    }
  })];

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, the issue was i was not able to get the data while posting using above mentioned header i.e.

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

While using jquery Ajax we were usually getting data in **response.body** at the backend server, but while implementing Angular ajax the data was not coming in response.body instead it was coming under

```
request.getParameterMap.keySet().iterator().next()
```