# AngularJS http.post() returns 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Hi and merry christmas to you all.

I am working with a Phonegap AngularJS App.  I am trying to make an http Post but I it returns an 404 error. I tried the POST using jquery 1.10.2 and it works. I have been days in this and it is the last part to finish coding the app.

I have tried different versions of the request with no success.

Here is the code

```
$scope.sendMail = function (user){ 
    console.log('sendmaul');


$http.post('https://cloud/email.aspx',
   {
        user: user.email,
        pass: user.password,
        to:user.recipient,
        subject:'Test',
        message:'My Message'
    }
    )
.success(function (data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('success');

})
.error(function (data,status,headers,config){
        console.log(data + status + config);
    });
}
```

I have read in many places that I need to add on a angular.module the following code as .config

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I added that code on controller.js but I don't see difference on behavior in my app. I also have many http.get() request that work really well.

--EDIT--

https://cloud.email.aspx is not a real site.

Comment: Have you looked @ network traces / debuggers to see what the differences in your request is with jquery and angular?  Have you tried curl?

Comment: I am testing inside my app because when testing locally I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' so it is very difficult to check anything else. This is my first app so I don't know how to implement curl with angular. If I remove POST method I get a 405. thanks for the response.

Comment: It seems a CORS problem.

Comment: I solved my CORS problem and I get a 200 status but it seems that DATA does not arrive. Again, jquery 1.10.2 works like a charm

Comment: Ha ha, did `sendmaul` make anyone else smile?

Answer (score 8):

Solved my problem.

After adding CORS and some Origins Exceptions on server side. I tried my code and got Success and 200 status response but the web service did nothing. After reading this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data) I found out that Angularjs post data different from jquery so a normal POST read on the web service would not work. That post have a link to this [site](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/) which explain in more detail my issue and it has some code for to send data the same way jquery does.

I hope this help someone

Comment: Dude, props to you! Fallowed the trail and got the damn explanation in the end. Thank you!