# $http doesn't send data to php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, http-post

```
var app = angular.module("report", []);

function index($scope, $http){

    $scope.auth = function(){
        $http({
            url: '/index.php/users/auth',
            method: "POST",
            data: {login: $scope.login, password: $scope.password}
        }).success(function(data){
               alert(data);
            });
    }

}
```

This is my AngularJS application. $http doesn't send POST data to the php script.

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function auth(){
        extract($_POST);
        echo $login;
    }
}
```

- This my php script.
Codeignitor return that undefined variable ***'login'***

Comment: To make sure if the Codeigniter doesn't "cleanup" your $_POST (for security purposes??), why don't your print_r($this->input->post());. Better still, use Chrome Developer window to check the Request (under Network tab) to see if the post param has been sent correctly.

Comment: Kind of off-topic, but use the console to check the data output on that success function. It'll help give you more insight (as @Yman suggested) into what is being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use file_get_contents function, provided by php.

You can find an explanation here:

[AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

You can find a code example here:

http://www.cleverweb.nl/javascript/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Please use json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

for example:

```
public function auth(){
    $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem without changing code in server and use `$_POST` the regular way. Explained here: http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/