# $http.post not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

When I use `$http.get` my code works, but if I use $http.post, I never get the parameters to the request .php file.

This is Service function:

```
    TestPanel.service('MySampleService', function ($http, $q) {
    this.getAllPosts = function () {       

        var def = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/data/AJAXRequest.php', 'mydata=1&abcd=2').success(function (data) {
            if (data == null)
                def.reject('ERROR: DATA IS NULL');
            else if (data.HasError)
                def.reject('ERROR: ' + data.Message);
            else
                def.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            def.reject('ERROR: Sorry, unable to complete your request.');
        });

        return def.promise;
    }
});
```

And Controller function:

```
 TestController.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'MySampleService',
    function ($scope, $http, MySampleService) {       

        function FetchPostsList() {
            MySampleService.getAllPosts().then(function (data) {
                $scope.lstPosts = data.ResponseData;
                $scope.totalRecords = data.totalRecords;
                console.info('DATA=' + $scope.lstPosts);
            },
            function (err) {
                console.info('err=' + err);
            });
        }

        FetchPostsList();
    }
]);
```

and 
My AJAXRequest.php file

```
<?php 
   var_dump($_POST)
?>
```

if I use **$http.post()**

**Output**:

```
 array (size=0)
  empty
```

If i use **$http.get()**

**my output is :**

```
array (size=2)
  'mydata' => string '1' (length=1)
  'abcd' => string '2' (length=1)
```

I checked the post in FireBug tool, that its sending data to my php file. but php file getting no params.

If I use **$.ajax** or **$.post** my code work and it gives the response.

Comment: This solution worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you specify the content-type in the headers, specifically like this:

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: '/data/AJAXRequest.php',
data: { mydata: 1, abcd: 2 },
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(....);
```

Found comments relating to PHP specifically from this question: [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

It would seem that Angular sends as application/json by default, which can confuse PHP.

Comment: The way you told me its almost work....i mean, if i set parameters like this "data: { mydata: 1, abcd: 2 }" it not works. but if i use parameters "data: 'mydata=1&abcd=2'" its works fine. maybe i have to set JSON header in php file. But anyways thanks for it.

Comment: FYI mydata=1&abcd=2 is serialized data. You can get angular 1.4 to do that automatically for you or you can use a transform request function. If find that easier so you can just use json data like JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue but I found that there is no issue in angular http post method, issue is there where I am trying to get post data.

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

I used this code to get the posted data from angular and its works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Post data like this:

```
$http.post('/data/AJAXRequest.php', { mydata: 1, abcd: 2 })
```

Comment: i did but still not work...i dont know why php file showing en empty message. if i use $.post jquery method its work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sectiontype',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {SectionTypeId:0, Name: $scope.message},
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
}).success(function (data) {
    alert(data);
}).error(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

headers must be added in the end of the array otherwise it won't work.