# $http.get works, $http.post doesn't

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http-post

So, I have this really simple snippet in a controller where I get data from an external file using `$http.get`, and it works great! But when I use `$http.post`, I get a `"syntaxerror: unexpected token < at object.parse(native)"` in my console.

I've included both versions below with the working `$http.get` commented out.

```
var blogCtrl = angular.module('blogCtrl', []);

blogCtrl.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    //$http.get('/angular_blog/assets/php/ajaxRequests.php?action=fetchSingleArticle&permalink='+$routeParams.articlePermaLink)
    $http.post('/angular_blog/assets/php/ajaxRequests.php', {action: 'fetchSingleArticle', permalink: $routeParams.articlePermaLink})
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.articleTitle = data.articleTitle;
        $scope.articleAuthor = data.articleAuthor;
        $scope.articleContent = data.articleContent;
        $scope.publishDate = data.publishDate;
        $scope.category = data.category;
        $scope.categoryPermaLink = data.categoryPermaLink;
    });
}]);
```

I already tried the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027721/http-post-not-working-in-angularjs), but it gave the same result.

Comment: Have you tried this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: try setting content-type.

Comment: I think your json is not proper. So angular is not able to parse. May be that is why you are getting syntax error. Can you provide value of this part : `$routeParams.articlePermaLink`. Thank you

Comment: @Shubham, I'm looking into that, thanks! govindpatel: $routeParams.articlePermaLink = "something", but that's not the issue, cause if I uncomment the get-line and outcomment the post-line (and change $_POST to $_GET in my PHP), it works just fine. I'm looking into changing the way my PHP interprets the json data send by my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was better to make my PHP-file understand a json post request, so instead of trying to grab strings with $_POST['string'], do this:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

and then when I want to use strings from the request:

```
$obj->{'string'}
```