# AngularJS can't sent POST request to SLIM Framework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hello I have this angularjs http.post() request  to slim php framework.

```
  'use strict';

   soup.factory('loginService',function($http){
    return {
        login:function(user){
                         console.log(user);

            var $promise = $http.post('api/vendor/slim/slim',user );
            return $promise;
    };
});
```

when I debug the `$_POST` it always return an empty array,

but when I use use `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`, slim php will return an error.

this is php function that handle the request.

```
function login(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER by id";
     try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        //print_r($users);
        $users = json_encode($users);


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

    var_dump($_POST);
    $test = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    //do something with the post data



}
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: I love questions like this one: _"I get an error. Please, help me debug !"_ (but you never get to see that error :))

Answer (score 1):

[$http](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/%24http) api say:

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url. 
>   **If the value is not a string, it will be JSONified.**

Try sending data as a string, something like this:

```
var $promise = $http({
    url: 'api/vendor/slim/slim',                                                method: 'POST',
    data: 'user=' + usr + '&password=' + pwd,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
});
```

Don't forget to include the `Content-Type` header.