# How to discern between model binding errors and model validation errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, model-validation

I'm implementing a REST API project using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0, and I'd like to return a 400 status code if model binding failed (because the request is syntactically wrong) and a 422 status code if model validation failed (because the request is syntactically correct but contains unacceptable values).

As an example, given an action like

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(
    [FromRoute] int id,
    [FromBody] ThingModel model)
```

I'd like to return a 400 status code when the `id` parameter in the route contains a non-digit character or when no body has been specified in the request and a 422 status code when the properties of `ThingModel` contain invalid values.

From what I've seen both `IValueProvider` and `IModelBinder` implementations add their errors to the request's `ModelStateDictionary` like the validators do, and there is no way to inject code between binding and validation.

How can I implement such a behavior?

Answer (score 3):

**Haven't checked option #1 yet, but:**

- **ModelState.[ValidationState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelvalidationstate?view=aspnetcore-2.1)** has 4 possible values (Unvalidated, Invalid, Valid, Skipped) where in case of **model binding errors** I do get **Unvalidated** as a value
- Also would consider using **ApiBehaviorOptions** (see sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145243/how-do-i-customize-asp-net-core-model-binding-errors/51159755)) to automatically return a **new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState)** - since in case of binding error with a NULL bound value there's nothing to do and in case of validation errors we probably can't do anything either.

**Quick notes for the ApiBehaviorOptions:**

- must use ApiController attribute (which requires also routing attribute on the controller level also and does alter the way binding works)
- **the default behaviour with ApiController attribute will return a BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState) without any extra code and configuration**
- if you decide to roll your own ApiBehaviorOptions - you must initialize it after service.AddMvc or need to use: services.PostConfigure(o => {}) which has similar effect
- ApiBehaviorOptions SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter has to be false for the InvalidModelStateResponseFactory to work

So in some cases a custom filter is a better solution (less changes).

Comment: Relates to: HttpPost FromBody properties does not bind (are null) - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129919/web-api-complex-parameter-properties-are-all-null/52824095#52824095

Comment: Thanks for "you must initialize it after service.AddMvc".

Comment: First bulletpoint is not gonna be any good. Following cases all return value `Invalid`: a) no body, b) failed model binding (due to invalid data type) and c) failed model validation (syntax is ok, but data does not pass validation criteria).

Comment: You could go for `ModelState.Root.ValidationState`, but that still would not be precise enough as you would get values `Invalid`/`Unvalidated`/`Unvalidated`, so you could not discern cases b) and c) from comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute below in your project

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new
            {
                message = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage))
            });
    }
}
```

Change your api like this

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(
    [FromRoute] int id,
    [FromBody] ThingModel model)
```

`id` contains a non-digit => 400

`model` does not pass annotation validation inside => 400

if you want to reject unacceptable values in model with `422` code, implement in your controller

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, when a filter/attribute is executed the model validation has already occurred, you already have in the ModelState both the binding errors and the validation errors.