# Custom response when Model binding fails ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to give a **custom response** when **Model binding** to the `API` fails by **datatype mismatch**.

**Example:** When someone tries to bind a `string` to `GUID` parameter in my API, currently I get following response.

```
    {
      "documentCategoryId": [
        "Error converting value \"string\" to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'documentCategoryId', line 2, position 32."
      ]
    }
```

Instead, I would like to say,

**processing error**

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145243/how-do-i-customize-asp-net-core-model-binding-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159755/8043806), to add a custom response based on your usecase add the below code In **Startup**

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        new ResponseObject("403", "processing error");
});
```

Where **ResponseObject** is a custom class

```
 class ResponseObject{
   public string Status;
   public string Message;
   ResponseObject(string Status, string Message){
     this.Status = Status;
     this.Message= Message;
   }
 }
```

When model binding fails api would return response like this

> { Status : "403",  Message : "processing error" }

You can customize the Response Object as you please.

Comment: I tried this Giddy, but don't know why the control isn't hitting this piece of code, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to customize BadRequest response with `FormatOutput` method like below :

```
 services.AddMvc()
         .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(FormatOutput(actionContext.ModelState));
                };
            });
```

Customize the `FormatOutput` method to your whims.

```
public List<Base> FormatOutput(ModelStateDictionary input)
    {
        List<Base> baseResult = new List<Base>();
        foreach (var modelStateKey in input.Keys)
        {
            var modelStateVal = input[modelStateKey];
            foreach (ModelError error in modelStateVal.Errors)
            {
                Base basedata = new Base();
                basedata.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                basedata.Field = modelStateKey; 
                basedata.Message =error.ErrorMessage; // set the message you want 
                baseResult.Add(basedata);
            }
        }
        return baseResult;
    }

 public class Base
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```