# Best practice to return a 400 bad request in ASP.NET Core if BindModelAsync fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, devextreme

I am using the DevExtreme ASP.NET Data helpers 
https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/blob/master/net/Sample/DataSourceLoadOptions.cs to easily show some data in front end grid from an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI.

Basically, the library offers a bunch of helpers for interpreting the data from the DevExtreme dxDataGrid 
requests when it works in server-side / remote mode (ie. see [`remoteOperations`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/remoteOperations)) with Entity Framework through the [`DataSourceLoader` class](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/blob/902dd90f1399d554e73fe84db994492386a386df/net/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/DataSourceLoader.cs).

It works pretty well with the requests made by the dxDataGrid itself, except that there is one use-case that bothers me a bit when I expose the endpoint through a Swagger and a random user sends the wrong request model (aka `DataSourceLoadOptions`), that is that most fields inherited from the parent class [`DataSourceLoadOptionsBase`](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/blob/902dd90f1399d554e73fe84db994492386a386df/net/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/DataSourceLoadOptionsBase.cs) are not filled properly which like shown in the code below will result in an exception... exception which will then trigger a 500 HTTP code return from the API resource.

It basically happens when [`DataSourceLoadOptionsParser`](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/blob/902dd90f1399d554e73fe84db994492386a386df/net/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/Helpers/DataSourceLoadOptionsParser.cs) involved in the binding process failed to deserialize properly one of the request model properties.

```cs
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DataSourceLoadOptionsBinder))]
public class DataSourceLoadOptions : DataSourceLoadOptionsBase 
{
}

public class DataSourceLoadOptionsBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
    {
        var loadOptions = new DataSourceLoadOptions();
        DataSourceLoadOptionsParser.Parse(loadOptions, key => bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).FirstOrDefault());
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(loadOptions);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Instead of a 500 error, I would rather like to return a 400 error indicating what field(s) is/are not suitable to perform that particular request.

But I am not too sure how I can achieve that, since the error prevents the ASP.NET Core binding process to go further ([Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)).

Comment: Is your controller an API controller - that is, decorated with the `[ApiController]` attribute? If so see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51145243/70345). Alternatively, in the case that `DataSourceLoadOptionsParser.Parse` fails, set `bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();` then check `ModelState.IsValid` as normal in your controller. I don't know if this will allow you to find out which request property(ies) were problematic, but it might be a start for you to figure out how to do such.