# Unable to access property after successfully deserializing JSON

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, f#, json.net

I receive the following error after deserializing some JSON and attempting to access root.items:

```
 root.items.Count |> should equal 2
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> root.items@ was null.

The JSON is the following:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Nikeza: F# Backwards Pipe Operator",
                "tags": [
                    "Elm",
                    "F#",
                    "Giraffe",
                    "Functional Programming",
                    "Software Development"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Giraffe: VS Code bug that doesn't show up in VS 20017 (3)",
                "tags": [
                    "Hangouts On Air",
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Software Craftsmanship Conference - London",
                "tags": [
                    "Programming",
                    "Software Development",
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Snippet =    { title: string; tags: Collections.Generic.List<String> }

[<CLIMutable>]
type Item =       { snippet : Snippet }

[<CLIMutable>]
type Response =   { items : Collections.Generic.List<Item> }

[<Test>]
let ``Apply tags to videos`` () =
    let  delimitedIds = ["id1";"id2";"id3"] |> String.concat ","
    let  url = String.Format(requestTagsUrl, apiKey, delimitedIds)
    let response = httpClient.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

    if response.IsSuccessStatusCode
        then let root = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response>() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
             root.items.Count |> should equal 2
        else Assert.Fail()
```

Comment: Can you please add the Code of your model-class? Otherwise it's not possible to see, if the Json does match the model.

Comment: My guess is either the http request is not returning the response you expect, or that ReadAsAsync does not work how you expect.  I would try replace the http request with a StringContent object with the json in it  to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hi. The Response record type defined above the test is the "model". response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response>()

Answer (score 1):

I have just written a test for it, and I can confirm that the deserialization part of it is correct. Check if the request is returning the response correctly.

```
open System
open Expecto

let json = 
    """
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "snippet": {
                    "title": "Nikeza: F# Backwards Pipe Operator",
                    "tags": [
                        "Elm",
                        "F#",
                        "Giraffe",
                        "Functional Programming",
                        "Software Development"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "snippet": {
                    "title": "Giraffe: VS Code bug that doesn't show up in VS 20017 (3)",
                    "tags": [
                        "Hangouts On Air",
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "snippet": {
                    "title": "Software Craftsmanship Conference - London",
                    "tags": [
                        "Programming",
                        "Software Development",
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    """

[<CLIMutable>]
type Snippet =    { title: string; tags: Collections.Generic.List<String> }

[<CLIMutable>]
type Item =       { snippet : Snippet }

[<CLIMutable>]
type Response =   { items : Collections.Generic.List<Item> }

[<Tests>]
let tests =
    testList "Test" [
        test "Testing deserialization" {
            let result : Response = Json.deserialize json
            Expect.equal result.items.Count 3 "Should have 3 items"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129919/web-api-complex-parameter-properties-are-all-null) worked for me:

In summary, I had to resort to retrieving the actual json string using the following:

```
json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Afterwards, I used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json)
```

**Appendix:**

```
if response.IsSuccessStatusCode
    then let json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
         let result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```