# Object is NULL when passed to Web API in .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, angular5

I am facing problem while passing object value to Web API. I am passing value using Anuglar5

```
{
    "Company_User_Process_ID": 68,
    "BankName": "1860 UBL , ABBOTTABAD",
    "ChallanNo": "",
    "AccountTitle": "",
    "AccountNo": "",
    "CompanyName": "sdasd",
    "RegistrationNo": "",
    "ProcessId": 1,
    "PaymentType": false,
    "Document_Pid": "",
    "HeadsOfAccount": []
}
```

But I am getting  `Null`. I got some help from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129919/web-api-complex-parameter-properties-are-all-null/24131860#24131860). But I observed that the object that I am passing is not same as I am getting in Web API with extra `{}`

```
{
  {
    "Company_User_Process_ID": 68,
    "BankName": "1860 UBL , ABBOTTABAD",
    "ChallanNo": "",
    "AccountTitle": "",
    "AccountNo": "",
    "CompanyName": "sdasd",
    "RegistrationNo": "",
    "ProcessId": 1,
    "PaymentType": false,
    "Document_Pid": "",
    "HeadsOfAccount": []
  }
}
```

Here is the Code of Web API

```
public async Task<ResponseObject<ChallanDetailViewModel>>   CreateChallanDetail(ChallanDetailViewModel model)
 {
     ...... My code here 
 }
```

Here is the Model Class

```
public class ChallanDetailViewModel
{
    public long Company_User_Process_ID { get; set; }

    public string BankName { get; set; }

    public string ChallanNo { get; set; }

    public string AccountTitle { get; set; }

    public string AccountNo { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }

    public int ProcessId { get; set; }

    public int PaymentType { get; set; }

    public string Document_Pid { get; set; }

    public List<String> HeadsOfAccount { get; set; }

}
```

Client Side code that is passing object

```
this.http.post(url, model).map((response: any) => { return 
response.json() }).toPromise();
```

Comment: content type and encoding is same ??

Comment: While passing the object are you wrapping the object to another object?

Comment: @user1672994 No I do not.

Comment: @PranayRana yes

Comment: You didn't include your asp.net model (and signature of your controller method) - so it's not much we can help with. Getting null usually means your model does not match json you post, but we don't know your model.

Comment: @Evk Please check updated Question

Comment: Still didn't include the model (definition of class `ChallanDetailViewModel`).

Comment: You should also post the client side code that is serializing and sending the model to your web API. Since, you mentioned that you are getting the object with extra curly braces, so it may be wrong in the way you are serializing the object.

Comment: @Thangadurai please check updated

Comment: @Evk please check udpated

Comment: `PaymentType` is `int` in your model, but you are passing `false` (boolean) there. Either change `PaymentType` to `bool` or pass integer there (`"PaymentType": 0` or something)

Comment: @Evk Thanks You Sir.

Comment: Did you get a work around?

Comment: @FelixToo yes I do

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's the case for you. While passing a `nested child list/collection` to the API, the model should initialize the list in the constructor like below in order for it to pick the binding:

```
public class ChallanDetailViewModel
{
    public ChallanDetailViewModel()
    {
        HeadsOfAccount = new List<string>();
    }
    //Other properties
    public List<String> HeadsOfAccount { get; set; }
}
```