# 404 not found when posting to localhost

Tags: php, html, angularjs, node.js

When a user enters some details I am trying to add them to the database via a POST to a file called `registerNewUser.php` However the POST never succeeds. I'm simply given a 404. Here is the post code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../../php/login/registerNewUser.php',
    data: newUser,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log("success");
}).error(function(status) {
    console.log("ERROR");
});
```

I have tried moving setting the url to `/registerNewUser.php` and moving `registerNewUser.php` to the base directory but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the network tab for the actual URL that's being called

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Comment: @mscdex not at all. OP, open debug tools, click network, send the request, click the request.  Check the details.

Comment: The actual url being called is http://127.0.0.1:8080/registerNewUser.php. I would imagine this should work as registerNewUser.php is in the same folder as index.html and home.html.

Comment: Also it says that the content type is text/plain. should this be application/json?

Comment: Where is the html file that houses this form (and the AngularJS)? Make sure you're ignoring anyting after the # in the URL, as that is never seen by the server and ignored by the browser when calculating pathing. I'm guessing that if you set url to "/php/login/registerNewUser.php" or potentially "registerNewUser.php" it will work. If you manually type "http://yourserver/php/login/registerNewUser.php" does it work (won't be a POST, but shouldn't get 404)?

Comment: if I manually type 127.0.0.1:8080/registerNewUser.php it asks me if I want to open the php file but it also gives me a 404 on the web page.

Comment: looks like you need to start the php process