# Parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Expressjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using Angular to POST to my API. As I'm dealing with CORS I have set the header as `www-form-urlencoded` to avoid the "pre-flight.

```
$http.post(url, {key1: value1, key2: value2},{"headers":{ "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

  });
```

The problem now is that I can't seem to parse the object being POSTed even though I have this in my `server.js` which I thought would do the job:

```
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I'm trying to access the POSTed values with `req.body.key1` but I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: Do you have that line above where you define your `.post` route?

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: In your route handler, add `console.dir({req:req,res:res})` to dump the contents of both the request and response to your console. Great way to debug/trace.

Comment: The console is showing that `req.body` is `{ '{"key1":"12345","key2":"abcde"}': '' 
}`

Comment: I think @loganfsmyth means that the body parser module needs to be included in a certain position in your middleware "stack". Basically, before any routes is the most important, but I usually place it after most other middleware (except error handlers).

Comment: body parser is before any routes - I've used `bodyParser.json()` happily which is on the line above. I think the POSTed data is malformed looking at my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, so the middleware is getting confused. Setting the `Content-Type` header tells the server what kind of data you are sending, but you aren't actually changing the format of the data anywhere because nothing has told Angular that you want to send `urlencoded` data, so the server is still getting JSON.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs) shows how to encode the data.

Comment: also use params: instead of data: