# How serialize objects with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I serialize an object without using the `$.param` jquery?

I want the object below:

```
var user = {username: 'ronald.araujo', password: '123456',};
```

to have the following output:

```
username=ronald.araujo&password=123456
```

Any suggestions? Remembering that I would do this using Angularjs or pure Javascript.

**EDIT**:

I am using the verb "save" ($resource) the angularjs. How could I set the header "application / x-www-form-urlencoded" and serialize?

Comment: Do you mean serialize it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format? There's a simple lib available here - https://github.com/iambumblehead/form-urlencoded

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Comment: There's no built-in tool to do that in Angular afaik. But why do you want to do that? You can send any kinf of `GET` request without having to manually add the datat into the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure javascript can do it just fine:

```js
function serializeObj(obj) {
    var result = [];

    for (var property in obj)
        result.push(encodeURIComponent(property) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[property]));

    return result.join("&");
}

var user = {
    username: 'ronald.araujo',
    password: '123456'
};

var serialized = serializeObj(user);
console.log(serialized); //username=ronald.araujo&password=123456
```

The link to original answer: [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`;

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

 var serializedUser = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(user);

});
```

you can see `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike).

Answer (score 0):

For angular 2 I think you can best use the following decorator https://github.com/pleerock/class-transformer to transform, serialize and deserialize objects.

To learn more about decorators see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html