# $http.post difference $.post

Tags: jquery, angularjs

First of all, check the following image:

[image]

The left part represents jquery´s POST:

```
($.post("localhost:65066/Store/Browse2?QualificatifsIDs=483", { responseType: "json" })
```

And the right is angular´s POST:

```
($http.post("localhost:65066/Store/Browse2?QualificatifsIDs=483", { responseType: "json" }))
```

The left result is the expected one. Why is there a difference?

Comment: There should be no difference in how they accept the JSON. This is server side.

Comment: They use different defaults for `content type` when sending. Problem is server side

Comment: Expected? Your Angular request is receiving the wrong answer?

Comment: You need to compare the full requests rather than the response. Something server side is changing the response based on a difference in the HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

Jquery request: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Angular request: Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

[How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Also do you want the response type in the payload or as a config option?

```
$http.post("localhost:65066/Store/Browse2?QualificatifsIDs=483", {}, { responseType: "json" })
```