# Ionic angular app sending POST to socket.io server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, ionic-framework

I have a previously working ionic app that talks to node server running socket.io server.

The socket server gets the POST but it's empty. It used to work perfectly.

I can send successfully using a REST client (PAW on mac) with no issues... the POST body is received in socket.io app.

Here's the angular code in my ionic app:

```
 var data = { username: 'bob', password: 'smith' }

var config = {
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
      }
    }
    $http.post('http://example.com:3000/login',data, config)

    .success(function(result) {
          //don't make it here

    }).error(function(data,status) {
      //make it here... no error code
    });
```

and in my socket.io app on the node server:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); //this is empty
  console.log("req.body.username: " + req.body.username);  //empty empty
});
```

To confirm, the app.post does execute...se we make it that far on teh server. but the body is empty.

Preflight issue? I am stumped...need this working tonight :(

Comment: I should mention..this behavior occurs both with a browser (ionic serve) and also on ios device (ionic build ios --> xcode run on device) so it really can't be a CORS issue.

Comment: Progress... I changed to config to `''Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and now I get some data on server. Console log output: `{ '{"username":"bob","password":"smith"}': '' }
req.body.username: undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The $http.post function takes `(url, data, [config])` as parameters. 
Reference : [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

By looking at your code, I think that have misplaced the parameters.

Try the following

```
var data = { username: 'bob', password: 'smith' }

var config = {
  headers : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
  }
}
$http.post('http://example.com:3000/login', data, config)
.success(function(result) {
  //don't make it here

}).error(function(data,status) {
  //make it here... no error code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding transformRequest function in the $http settings:

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)