# Multipart/form-data form sending data with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to post form data as below to URL which is a webapi and the method is post

```
var surveyData = {
            Name: xyz,
            SetReminder: 'false',
            NoOfReminder: '0',
            StartDate: 'xyz',
            EndDate: 'xyz',
            Language: 'eng-us',
            Duration: '1',
            ApplicationName: 'xyz',
            SurveyTypeName: 'zxy'
        };
```

i have written the below code which call the post method of wbeapi but the function is able to send the data but the post method is not able to read the data that is send using the angular js.

```
function(surveyData) {
               return $http.post(URL , surveyData,{
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                });
```

Comment: I think the first answer on this question holds the answer you seek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs

Comment: that code given in the link doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if web api is Multipart/form-data then you need to create key value pair in the below form so that multi part form data will be created.

```
var objFormData = new FormData();
                for (var key in surveyData)
                    objFormData.append(key, surveyData[key]);
```

then you need to send the created multi part form data using the below code:

```
 return $http.post(URL, objFormData, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
var data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["surveyData"];
```

To recieve the json data from your multipart form.

If your multipart form contail files, then to get these files use :

```
System.Web.HttpFileCollection postedfiles = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

Also keep in mind that do not use any parameter in your controller action method.

Make sure you import these namespaces:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
```

**EDIT :**

modify your javascript code.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("surveyData", angular.toJson(surveyData));
```

> If you want to add images/other, you can add those using the code
>   below.

```
//data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[0]);
```

So your code will be :

```
function(surveyData) {
               return $http.post(URL , data,{
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                });
```

Now you will be able to receive the json data using

```
var data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["surveyData"];
```

and images/otherfiles(If you have) using

```
System.Web.HttpFileCollection postedfiles = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

Comment: data is null value when i use var data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["surveyData"];