# Problems using $http POST

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-http

I am new in angular.js and I need to make form with 2 fields for numbers and when I click on submit i need to send to server with json for request result of suma. It will look like: 4 in first field , 4 in second field and on submit it will return result 8.

Thanks guys. Here is code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HttpGetController">
    <p>Num1 
        <input type="number" name="num1" ng-model="num1" required />
    </p> 
    <p>Num2: 
        <input type="number" name="num2" ng-model="num2" required />
    </p> 
    <button ng-click="SendData()">Saberi</button> <hr /> 
         {{ PostDataResponse }}
 </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SendData = function () { 
        var data = $.param({ num1: $scope.num1, num2: $scope.num2 });
        var config = { headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;' } }

        $http.post('localhost:3000', data, config) 
             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        })
     }
});
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how your bindings are set on the form controls. Also there are lots of tutorials available regarding forms

Comment: Like @charlietfl show us what you have tried.. see mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: AngularJS normally uses `content-type, 'application/json'`. Otherwise look at [URL-encoding variables using only AngularJS services](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970229/5535245).

Comment: Example with JSON [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h80vq6wq/)

Comment: @georgeawg work with you example! Thank you, and thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0):

Get the input values and that will be automatically bind to scope. In your controller, just add those two operands.

```
$scope.sum = $scope.op1 + $scope.opt2;
```

then post the $scope.sum to server using **`$http.post()`** or thru $resource service.

Comment: Thanks guys. Here is code:

`<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HttpGetController">
    <p>Num1 <input type="number" name="num1" ng-model="num1" required /></p>
    <p>Num2: <input type="number" name="num2" ng-model="num2" required /></p>
    <button ng-click="SendData()">Saberi</button>
    <hr />
    {{ PostDataResponse }}
</div>`

Comment: ` var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {           
            var data = $.param({
                num1: $scope.num1,
                num2: $scope.num2
            });
        
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }
`

Comment: And the lest part :

 ` $http.post('localhost:3000', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })`

Answer (score 0):

### $http POST with JSON Data Example

```
app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SendData = function () { 

        var data = { num1: $scope.num1, num2: $scope.num2 };

        $http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data) 
            .then(function (response) {
                  $scope.PostDataResponse = response.data.data;
        })
     }
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://jsfiddle.net/h80vq6wq/)