# PHP not responding for Angularjs Request

Tags: php, angularjs

I  have a Raw form with some angularjs Validation,

```
<form name = "sform" novalidate="true">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            First name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" placeholder="First Name" required="true" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]*$/">
        </td>
        <td ng-show="sform.fname.$invalid && !sform.fname.$pristine"  class="help-block">wrong name </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Last Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="lname" placeholder="last Name" required="true" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]*$/">
        </td>
        <td ng-show= "sform.lname.$invalid && !sform.lname.$pristine"  class="help-block">wrong Last name </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="email" required="true">
        </td>
        <td ng-show="sform.email.$invalid && !sform.email.$pristine"  class="help-block">wrong Email </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="sform.$invalid" ng-click = "submitForm()">Submit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>       
</table>
</form>
```

And related .js files are

**far_app.js**

```
var farLogin = angular.module('far_login',[]);
```

**far_formcontroler.js**

```
farLogin.controller('far_formcontrol',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.url='http://localhost/far_submit.php';
     var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

        // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
            alert('our form is amazing'+$scope.fname+' '+$scope.email+' '+$scope.lname); 
            // check to make sure the form is completely valid
            if ($scope.sform.$valid) {
                $http.post($scope.url,{"name": $scope.fname, "email": $scope.email, "lname": $scope.lname},config).
                 success(function() {
                            alert('our form is amazing'+$scope.fname+' '+$scope.email+' '+$scope.lname); 
                        })

            }
            else
            {
                alert('our form is not amazing');   
            }

        }

    }]);
```

And my **php file** is

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("this is php")</script>
<?php
?>
```

But the php script is not at all executing and their are no error in browser's console.

Where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set controller somewhere in your html?

Comment: ya i did its inside  div tag covering all the form

Comment: Can you see the http request to the PHP script inside the browser debugger? I dont know angular, but maybe its not accepting html content. Try raw javascript without tha html script tag.

Comment: Can you console log this `{"name": $scope.fname, "email": $scope.email, "lname": $scope.lname}` before your post request and let me know the output? also can you check the network request to see if the request is actually going through?

Comment: `Object {name: "name", email: "email@domine.com", lname: "lastname"}` thsi is the output of console.log before sending request

Comment: that is the output @Ravish

Comment: are you seeing our form is amazing alert?

Comment: I suggest you console.log the error return of the .post(), or the return of the $http. - I'm not an angular js dev (PHP Dev)...

Comment: ya i do @belthazorNv

Comment: Change your success handler to `success(function(data) {alert(data);})` and you should see the output of your php file. However, it'll just be text - the `script` won't actually be executed.

Comment: I'm not getting any output for `success(function(data) {alert(data);})` @fridge_light

Comment: Ok, it's working for me locally. There's some other problem then.

Comment: did you used the code from the questions? @fridge_light

Comment: I did, yes, with `far_formcontrol` as the controller within a wrapping `div`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109999/discussion-between-narasimha-maiya-and-fridge-light).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are couple good threads on Angular $http post issues in SO itself, for example have a look at following thread: [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs) or this one : [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

**Note:** You need to run this using a web server locally. code below is working for me "a OK", I did following:

- Downloaded the code you have provided
- Save all of them in a local directory
- Started php built in web server `php -S 0.0.0.0:8181`, accessed the index.html at : http://localhost:8181/ submitted the form and it returned me a json response : `{"status":"OK","data":{"userid":null}}`

Pastebin: [far_app.js](http://pastebin.com/x2x6vhB4), [index.html](http://pastebin.com/ZRakWMD3), [far_login.php](http://pastebin.com/EqU4Whck)

I used PHP built in server just for the testing purpose, but, I highly recommend you use something like **Wampp** or **Xampp** on Windows to run this. You can manually configure your Apache/PHP/Mysql as well, but, Wampp/Xampp are pretty easy to install and get started with.

I've restructured the code a bit, something like following:

```
    angular.module('far_login',[])
.controller('far_formcontrol',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        console.log('First Name : ' , $scope.fname);
        console.log('Email : ' , $scope.email);
        console.log('Last Name: ', $scope.lname); 
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if ($scope.sform.$valid) {
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:8181/far_submit.php',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: {"name": $scope.fname, "email": $scope.email, "lname": $scope.lname}
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(function  (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        } else {
            alert('our form is not amazing');   
        }
    };
}]);
```

this is based on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) from  [Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), and the  **far_submit.php** file like:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = [ 'status' => 'OK', 'data' => [ 'userid' => $autogeneratedUserId] ];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Make sure the the **far_submit.php** is accessible at http://localhost/far_submit.php