# AngularJS Add Header Authorization for Token

Tags: angularjs, header, cors, authorization, token

So, i've been digging for the last two days but i have no idea why this won't work..

here's the problem, i try to make request to an api server and i have to add a token in the request, but when i add the token to header authorization, i've got response 405 from the server

this api i've tested on postman and its work, but when i implement to angular it doesn't work

this my code:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        })
```

and this is the req header from chrome:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDdlr.png)

so in this case, is this my code, or the server problem ??

Comment: One problem i see is that you are doing a form-urlencoded post not the standard json post. The `data` needs to be transformed. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs

Comment: i've transformed the data correctly, if i'm not include header authorization req is work, and result json response form the server, but when i try to add header authorization, it won't work

Comment: You can look at the network log for errors.

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9999' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

error in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

```
  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);
authInterceptor.$inject = ["$q","$location"];
function authInterceptor($q, $location) {
        return {
          // Add authorization token to headers
            request: function (config) {
             // get token from a cookie or local storage
            var token = "token string ";
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
            return config;
          },
          // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
          responseError: function(response) {

            if(response.status === 401) {
             // redirect to some page

              // remove any stale tokens
              return $q.reject(response);
            }
            else {
              return $q.reject(response);
            }
          }
        };
      }
```

then inject the interceptor like this

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

Comment: maybe the token that you are using is not valid or expired

Comment: even if the token expired at least its return json correctly and i got the error message from server that token was expired