# AngularJS post method is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postman

I'm trying to sends some data along with a post to a specific url which has a php script behind it. At this moment I don't have access to the php script. The php script checks if the string matches any record in the db and returns that record if there is a match. If there is no match the script will return all the records.

The following code is what I have so far. As you can see I have a string 
named: shouldnotfindanyresultsstring. This should actually not return any results. However it returns all records instead of no records.

What I tried:

- Use `params` instead of `data`
- use different `Content-types`
- use the short version of the post method

---

```
$http({
    url: $scope.url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: {search: "shouldnotfindanyresultsstring"}
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function (response) { // optional
    console.log("Still not working");
});
```

So eventually I want to search records in the db with the search string. However I do not get it working.

With postman I can generate a post which works. I do have a strong feeling that it has something to do with the `Content-type`

Comment: Can you post the HTTP request that is done by Postman?

Comment: Getting data from the server without altering any should be a GET method. It isn't relevant to your question but I thought you should know this if you didn't.

Comment: @str Not sure if this is want you mean but I add a `key`: search and a `value`: stringwithnoresults. In postman this gives me the result `null`. In the app this returns me all of the records

Comment: @Thijs Yes I know this but I need to search with a string for some records

Comment: @RSSD That is ambiguous. Please click "Generate Code" in Postman for your request and post the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then format your data as a string

```
data: "search=shouldnotfindanyresultsstring"
```

If you want to use 'application/json' then use this:

```
var jsonData = { search : "shouldnotfindanyresultsstring" };

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
}).
    success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).
    error(function (message, status) {
        console.log(message);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this one actually works! I use `data : "search=shouldnotfindanyresultsstring"`

Comment: Great! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http.post($scope.url, JSON.stringify("shouldnotfindanyresultsstring"), { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} })
```

or this:

```
 $http.post($scope.url, JSON.stringify({search: "shouldnotfindanyresultsstring"}), { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` you need to actually encode the data as a string. Angular always posts your object as a JSON encoded object in your body, even if you specify that header.

It's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24964658/1372883) and provides the solution