# Get values and pass to api ionic angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, curl, ionic-framework

I have a form:

```
<form name="loginform" novalidate class="css-form">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Email" required>
             <p class="error validationerror"
      ng-show="loginform.email.$invalid && loginform.email.$touched">
      Must be a valid email</p>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <p class="error validationerror"
      ng-show="loginform.password.$invalid && loginform.email.$touched">
      Password is required</p>
  </label>

</div>
{{value}}
<input type="submit" ng-click="Login(user)" class="button button-dark marginauto loginformbtn" value="Login">
</form>
```

and what I want to do is this I want to grab the user.username and the user.password and I want to pass them to a api I know how to grab them but I do not know how to send them as POST to the URL like with cURL in PHP.

here is the angular js code I have:

```
$scope.Login = function(user) {
    $scope.value = {};
};
```

Please help thank you

Comment: Learn about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do `$http.post` method in angularjs

in your problem

```
 $scope.login= function(user){

         var value = {
                        "UserName":user.username,
                        "PassWord":user.password
                     };


          $http.post("place your http service here",value)
                .success(function(res){
                   console.log(res);
                 })
                .error(function(res){
                   console.log(res);
                 });
```

To know more about `$http` look in the official [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)