# How to manage http content-type in web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, content-type

I am developing an application on angular that makes several http request to the server which are mostly POST and GET request.

I wanted to know if we can use a mix of both

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json
```

as per the request i.e
One request uses application/json and the other application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Or is it a good practice to only use one content-type.

Comment: Mainly content type comes from server side. Since server knows which type of response it is sending. It is not possible to mix both. Only possible for different response itself.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh What I mean is one request is application/json and the other is application/x-www-form-urlencoded...is that a good practice..

Comment: Highly possible from server side. Off course this is a good practice.

Comment: Yes, you can change the content type of your POST requests (and GET too but they have no request body so it doesn't matter) via headers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970229/283366