# AngularJS : Prevent auto surrounding quotes to post values in $http post request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a post request that sends some token post parameters. Value `token` doesn't surrounded with any quotes. But, when making `http` request, the `token` get automatically wrapped with single/double quotes.

Here's the code that makes `$http` POST request,

```
var data = { YII_CSRF_TOKEN : token};
console.info(token);
$http.post('..some url here..', data).success (function (response){

});
```

BTW, Logging the token gives me the token which has no quotes wrapped.

Current result,

[image]

You could see the value of token gets automatically surrounded with quotes.

My expected output to be like,

[image]

Comment: Are you just talking about the quotes in the console? Or it really is sending to the server with the quotes?

Comment: Not in console. But Yes, it sending to the server with the quotes.

Comment: that what json stringify does.. if you dont want to send json.. change the `contentType` to `application/text`

Comment: The token (or `YII_CSRF_TOKEN` in your JSON) is a string and therefore **must** be quoted. It appears the server is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: If that `console.info` returns value like `"18v789uh"`, then your `token` must be wrapped in quotes as well. Such as `token = '"18v789uh"'`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970229/283366) in the duplicate question

Comment: @Phil thanks, that helped.