# AngularJS SpringSecurity CORS issue

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I'm setting up an Angular+Spring Security module to login and registering users.
When I register an user, everything is OK. The final step after register is automatically login but I'm having this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http//localhost:8080/com-tesis/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http//localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

The angularJs side services:

```
.factory("sessionAccountService", function($http){
        var session = {};
        session.login = function(data){
            return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/com-tesis/login",
                              "username="+data.name+"&password="+data.password,
                              {headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type"}}
            ).then(function(data){
                alert("loggin correcto");
                localStorage.setItem("session",{});
            }, function(data){
                alert("error login in");
            });

        };
        session.logout = function(){
            localStorage.removeItem("session");
        };
        session.isLoggedIn = function(){
            return localStorage.getItem("session") !== null;
        }
        return session;
    })
  .factory("accountService", function($resource){
        var service = {};
        service.register = function(account, success, failure){
            var Account = $resource("http://localhost:8080/com-tesis/rest/accounts");
            Account.save({},account,success,failure);
        };
        service.userExists = function(account, success, failure){
            var Account = $resource("http://localhost:8080/com-tesis/rest/accounts");
            var data = Account.get({name:account.name}, function(){
                var accounts = data.accounts;
                if (accounts.length !== 0){
                    success(accounts[0]);
                } else {
                    failure();
                }
            }, 
            failure);
        }
        return service;
    });
```

This is the CORS filter implemented on backend side:

```
package tesis.core.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

This the filter on web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            tesis.core.security.SimpleCORSFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I'm confussed, this are the Chrome Network requests:
[req/res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6anj5.jpg)

I don't realize what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

EDIT:
When I send request from same url http//localhost:8080/ works perfectly. From http//localhost:9000 spring always return SC_UNAUTHORIZED

This is the SecurityConfig

```
package tesis.core.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthFailure authFailure;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccess authSuccess;

    @Autowired
    private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authSuccess)
                .failureHandler(authFailure)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

The AuthSuccess and AuthFailure class

```
package tesis.core.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthSuccess extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

}

package tesis.core.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthFailure extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours reply, anyways, when I send request from same url http//localhost:8080/ works perfectly. From http//localhost:9000 spring alwaoys return SC_UNAUTHORIZED. I'm edited the answer

Comment: @Fede: Add server log to your question. Is there any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution. First of all, to solve the 401 error, I rewrited the request as it says here: [401 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs/24964658#24964658)

After that, a new error appeared:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Origin is therefore not allowed access.

Then, reading Spring doc I realized that I must say specifically to spring which header to use. Here the clue: [Spring Doc: header-static](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-static)

So, this is the SecurityConfig file fixed:

```
package tesis.core.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthFailure authFailure;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccess authSuccess;

    @Autowired
    private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"))
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authSuccess)
                .failureHandler(authFailure)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone.