# ionic $http post not sending data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to post data to a web service but the data is missing.

Here is the code

```
        var product = {
          CategoryID: 'test'
        };

        $http({
          url: URL,
          method: "POST",
          data: product,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config) {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

The POST data on the server is empty.

I have set up Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-MethodAccess-Control-Allow-Headerss and Access-Control-Allow-Headers on the server.

This API works fine when tested through Postman

Comment: You your browser debugger to see what is actually sent and compare that to what is sent using Postman. There is obviously a difference somewhere but you will have to be the one that finds it.

Comment: @Igor I have and there does not appear to be a difference. The ionic app even has a Content-Length that is non zero.

Comment: can you tell us more about how you retrieve data on the server side ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs). Encode the data with the [$httpParamSerializer service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue try a look at this one [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs) - you probably need to transform your request in order to sent in via `$http` service with the required content type.

Comment: I had to change the data to, data: "CategoryID="+encodeURLComponent(CategoryID),