# id showing undefined when trying to implement delete in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to implement delete funtion in angularjs. The backend in asp.net is working fine. when i check with postman its working fine. now am trying to the front end for that. when i hit the delete button. its not getting the UId. its showing like this.

```
http://localhost:50802/api/User/BUser/[object%20Object]
```

am totally new to angular. i dont know whether this angular code is correct or not.And another thing is i need to implement user confirmation popup window also. please help me...

angular controller.

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (data, UId) {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: urls.api + 'User/BUser/' + UId,

            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);

        })
    };
```

HTML

```
 <tr ng-repeat="d in UserList">

                        <td>{{d.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.path}}</td>
                        <td><button ng-click="DeleteUser()">Delete </button></td>

                    </tr>
```

here my Asp.net Controller

```
[HttpDelete]
        [Route("DeleteBanner/{UId}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteBanner(int UId)
        {
            int? result = await _service.DeleteBannerAsync(UId);

            return Ok();

        }
```

Comment: in the ng-click function call, pass the parameters to the function

Comment: You do **not** need to stringify the data. Angular does it by default

Comment: @phil am new to angular. this code is taken from a tutorial. actually i dont know this code will work or not. sorry if its wrong. can you provide one working answer.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka its not working bro.

Comment: I would definitely find another tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the valuable comments. i found the error. in the asp.net controller i used **HttpDelete**. But here Am geting the data in **Post** method. that is the problem.
and Also as Phil said, I dont need to mind about that `Json.stringify(data)` things.

here is the Answer.

angular Controller

```
 $scope.DeleteUser = function (Uid) {
        deleteUser = $window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
        //console.log(Uid);
        if (deleteUser) { 
            $http({
                method: "Delete",
                url: urls.api + 'User/BUser/' + Uid,
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data);
            })
        }
    };
```

Html

```
<button ng-click="DeleteUser(d.Uid)">Delete </button>
```

well if i wasted your time really sorry for that. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your function inside the controller expects the parameter Id and data, i assume your data refers to the Object **`user`**, change the html as follows,

```
  <td><button ng-click="DeleteUser(d)">Delete </button></td>
```

and then,

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (user) {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: urls.api + 'User/BUser/' + user.UId,    
            data: user
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
        })
    };
```

Comment: Where is `data` gone?

Comment: @Phil You dont need that actually, he is expecting the id to be passed

Comment: What about `JSON.stringify(data)`? Where is that `data` variable coming from?

Comment: yeah right! probably he is passing the whole user data

Comment: @Sajeetharan its not working for me. again its showing the same error.
well this is my .net controller. may be it can helps you. please help me.  




 '[HttpPost]
        [Route("BUser/{UId}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(int UId)
        {
            int? result = await _service.DeleteUserasync(UId);

            return Ok();

        }'

Comment: you could debug and check if there are correct values being passed

Comment: well this is working fine when i check with postman.
my problem is in the angular controller

Comment: @Coder what form of data is your controller expecting? If it's meant to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970229/283366

Answer (score 2):

There are many patterns to follow. But let me answer your question first, then suggest a better pattern:
Your ng-click event is not taking any parameter, it should look like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in UserList">
  ...
  <td><button ng-click="DeleteUser(d.UId)">Delete </button></td>
</tr>
```

And since your .NET API Controller expects a parameter called **UId** as shown below,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("BUser/{UId}")] 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(int UId) {
//Implementation
}
```

then in Angular, you must tag that parameter with that tag name: **params: { UId: id }**. Also, since you want to prompt the user to confirm the action, I'd suggest you to use [Bootbox Js](http://bootboxjs.com/) as follows:
    It's a small, powerful, easy to use javascript library. Just provide a link     to it on your index file.

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    var url = urls.api + 'User/BUser/' + id;
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $http.post(url, { params: { UId: id } })
            .then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Better Pattern**: I would suggest controller-service pattern as follows:
The **service** would look like:

```
function deleteUser(id) {
    var url = urls.api + 'User/BUser/' + id;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(url, { params: { UId: id } })
        .then(success).catch(deferred.reject);
    return deferred.promise;

    function success(response) {
        var data = response && response.data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
}
```

Then in the **controller**:

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            /*
             * You can use Angular blockUI to show progress here
            */
            return userService.deleteUser(id).then(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }).finally(function () {
                 //You can stop the blockUI instance here.
                //appBlockUI.stop();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That's just a tip for you to research in that line of thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Change your `tr` to

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in UserList">
  <td>{{d.description}}</td>
  <td>{{d.path}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="DeleteUser(d, d.UId)">Delete </button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment brother.  can you say how the angular  controller looks like??

Comment: @Coder use same code as you posted in your question :)

Comment: `http://localhost:50802/api/User/BUser/[object%20Object]` 

after i implemented that its showing this error. why is that?

Comment: print `data` and  `UId` and take its screenshot and update in question