# Angular $http.post is not sending the entire form

Tags: angularjs, perl, cgi

A simple angular 1.x $https.post which submits a name ("J Doe") and a phone number (1234567):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.insertData=function(){
            $http.post("cgi-bin/in.cgi",{
              'bname':$scope.bname,
              'bphone':$scope.bphone
               }).then(function(response){
                    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                },function(error){
                    alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                    console.error(error);

                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form>
            Name:- <input type="text" ng-model="bname" />
            Phone:-<input type="text" ng-model="bphone" />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertData()" />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

To a Perl script which does an insert into MySQL:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use DBI;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use JSON;

my $sql;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('****', '****', '****') || die "Connecting from Perl to MySQL database failed: $DBI::errstr";

my $cgi   = CGI->new;
my $name  = $cgi->param('bname') || "unknown";
my $phone = $cgi->param('bphone') || "unknown";

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";

$sql =  "insert into TestDB values ('$name', '$phone')";
$dbh->do("$sql") || die ("Connecting from Perl to MySQL database failed: $DBI::errstr");

$dbh->disconnect;

print "Record insert successfully";
```

But the only thing being inserted into the DB is:

```
+---------+---------+
| Name    | Phone   |
+---------+---------+
| unknown | unknown |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The name and phone are nowhere, but a print of $cgi->param('POSTDATA') give the following:

```
 {"json":"J Doe"}
```

OK, I found the name, "J Doe", along with some weird "json" key, but where's the phone number?
What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you remove || "unknown" from the assignments for $name and $phone?

Comment: Without the || "unknown" an execution error is thrown because $name and $phone are not set.  Apparently, $cgi->param('name'), etc. don't exist.

Comment: It sounds like you have a mismatch of your data types. As the answer below indicates, you are mixing form encoding paradigms. What format would you like to send the data in?

Comment: Json format would be fine.  I

Comment: Then you should set the content-type header to 'application/json' and use the browser debugger to ensure that the payload is encoded as json.

Comment: header : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting $http.post's header to type json:

```
header : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

$cgi->param('POSTDATA') became

```
{ "bname" : "J Doe", "bphone" : "1234567" }
```

From there, Perl's decode_json converted the string to a hash which finished off the problem.

```
my $decoded = decode_json($cgi->param('POSTDATA'));
$sql =  "insert into TestDB values ('$decoded->{bname}', '$decoded->{bphone}')";
```

Stackoverflow comes through again.

Comment: The AngularJS default for content type is `application/json`. I am surprised that it was not already sending that. Did your code override that default somewhere? For more information, see [AngularJS $http API Reference - Setting HTTP Headers.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)

Comment: Originally, POSTDATA had something that looked like the data I wanted (see original posting), but not until I followed Jason's suggestion of explicitly declaring the header as "application/json" did POSTDATA contain all the data in json format.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, whenever you post using that mode you need to add the data on the posted url as a querystring.

It would look like this:

```
$scope.insertData=function(){
        $http.post("cgi-bin/in.cgi?bname=" + $scope.bname + "&bphone=" + $scope.bphone, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
           }).then(function(response){
                console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
            },function(error){
                alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                console.error(error);

            });
        }
    });
```

But you would need to properly encode the values you are sending, please refer to the following link for more information: 
[How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Hope that helps.