# Base 64 Image to ocr.space API Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, post, ionic2, ocr, angular-http

I am trying to send a base 64 Jpeg to an API for OCR analysis.

The API docs can be found here https://ocr.space/ocrapi

The code to save the Image is here:

```
takePicture() {
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit:true }).then((imageData)=>{
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    });
 }
```

However I'm sure this is all fine as copying the base 64 string and sending via postman works fine.

This is how I send the string to the API.

```
post(val) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('apikey', 'APIKEY');

    let data = 'base64Image=' + val;
    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post('http://api.ocr.space/parse/image', data, {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

The base 64 string is passed to the val variable.

The given error is : "Not a valid base64 image. The accepted base64 image format is 'data:image/;base64,'."

Odd that it works fine in postman.... can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you appending `data:image/jpeg;base64,` to the `base64image` variable?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I believe that is the correct format?

Comment: Yeah but doesn't the `imageData` variable already have that?

Comment: `The return value is sent to the cameraSuccess callback function, in one of the following formats, depending on the specified cameraOptions: A String containing the Base64-encoded photo image.` -> https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html#cameragetpicturesuccesscallback-errorcallback-options

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Surprisingly not, It needs to be appended to the string.

Comment: Ah okay.. weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you're sending over the data. If you look at the [Postman collection](https://github.com/A9T9/OCR.Space-OCR-API-Code-Snippets/blob/master/OCR.space%20OCR%20API.postman_collection.json) with API call examples, you'll see that the `base64image` is being sent as `form-data`.

[image: Postman call]

But, as stated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24964658/1623249),

> When we want to post the value as a FORM post, we need to change the
>   serialization algorithm and post the data with the content-type,
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

So this code should work:

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'apikey': 'helloworld'
};
var data = {
  'base64image': 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...'
}

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
    headers: headers,
    data: data,
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
      var str = [];
      for (var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
    },
  })
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/aPO4UGng7uaMbIqrzc7J

Comment: Fixed in a simpler way based on the code i already had, but your answer is very much correct! Thanks very much!

Comment: @calmcalmuncle please consider upvoting answers if they were helpful, instead of saying thank you :) [More info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment)