# Not a valid base64 image

Tags: api, curl, ocrspace-ocr-api

[image]

I'm trying to semd a base64 encoded fimage to the ocr.space api following https://ocr.space/blog/2016/10/ocr-api-supports-base64.html and https://ocr.space/ocrapi . You can see my Postman settings in the screenshot.

However when I submit it I see:

```
"ErrorDetails": "Not a valid base64 image. The accepted base64 image format is 'data:<content_type>;base64,<base64_image_content>'. Where 'content_type' like 'image/png' or 'image/jpg' or 'application/pdf' or any other supported type.",
```

Using Postman I have created the following curl request https://pastebin.com/ajfC3a5r

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base 64 Image to ocr.space API Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826777/base-64-image-to-ocr-space-api-ionic-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your base64 data at [here](https://pastebin.com/ajfC3a5r), `\n` is included.
- When I tried to decode the base64 data after `\n` was removed from the base64 data, it was found that the data was PDF file. The content type was not `image/png`.

By these, I think that the error which was shown at your question occurs. So please modify as follows.

#### Modified curl command:

1. Please remove `\n` from the base64 data.
2. About the header of base64 data, please modify from `data:image/png;base64,##### base64 data #####` to `data:application/pdf;base64,##### base64 data #####`.

When above modifications were done, how about using the following curl command?

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.ocr.space/parse/image \
  -H "apikey:#####" \
  -F "language=eng" \
  -F "isOverlayRequired=false" \
  -F "iscreatesearchablepdf=false" \
  -F "issearchablepdfhidetextlayer=false" \
  -F "base64Image=data:application/pdf;base64,##### base64 data #####"
```

#### Result:

When above sample is run, the following value is returned.

```
{
  "ParsedResults": [
    {
      "TextOverlay": {
        "Lines": [],
        "HasOverlay": false,
        "Message": "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested"
      },
      "TextOrientation": "0",
      "FileParseExitCode": 1,
      "ParsedText": "##### text data #####",
      "ErrorMessage": "",
      "ErrorDetails": ""
    }
  ],
  "OCRExitCode": 1,
  "IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
  "ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "123",
  "SearchablePDFURL": "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested."
}
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I could confirm that the API worked using above modified base64 data and sample curl.

  - The curl sample including the modified base64 data is [this](https://pastebin.com/jYGm2imx).
  - If you use this, please set your API key.
- Or you can also directly use the image file which is not base64 data. The sample curl is

  ```
    curl -X POST https://api.ocr.space/parse/image -H "apikey:#####" -F "file=@sample.png"
  ```