# Post null value from ionic to asp.net web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I tried to make a post request from ionic to web api this way

ionic code

```
$http({
              url: 'http://localhost:1449/api/IonicApi',
              method: "POST",
              data: {
            firstName : "a",
            lastName : "b",
            email : "ab@ab.com"
          },
              headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }
          }).then(function (response) {
              // success
              $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Your Name is '+$scope.man.firstName + ' '+$scope.man.lastName,
                template: 'It might taste good'
            })
          }, function (response) { // optional
              // failed
              console.log('failed');

          });
```

and the c# part is

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post(tblPerson person)
        {
            db = new MobileDBEntities();
            db.tblPersons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
```

I tried from postman to post data it was working. But from Ionic it is passing null data of object
[image]

What wrong did I make here?

Postman screenshot I am adding here
[image]

Comment: Try changing the `content-type` header to `application/json`

Comment: Tried that already. In that case it is not even hitting the wep api controller.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your Postman request looks like?

Comment: I have added that after you have told. Can you please check?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http

Comment: Have you mentioned type of call over api like [Get] or [Post] and tried ?

Comment: yes, I tried that. Same problem.@Arun

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to call you api like below where obj is your data

```
$http.post('http://localhost:1449/api/IonicApi',obj).success(function(){

}).error(function()
{
});
```

Comment: I tried that previously. It was not hitting the api.

Comment: This is a suggestion for Arun: don't use .success() and .error(). These are deprecated methods and completely removed in AngularJS 1.6.