# Web Api Insert Works in Postman but not from code

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, insert, postman, angularjs-http

The following simple insert record method works in Postman but I can not get it to work in my AngularJS controller.

> ```
> Postman Headers (Post)  
> Key ContactID  Value 0  
> Key FName      Value John  
> Key LName      Value Smith  
> Key Cache-Control Value no-cache  
> Key Content-Type  Value application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> ```

```
$scope.insert = function () {

 var obj = { "ContactID": 0, "FName": "John", "LName": "Smith" };

 var url = "http://********************.net/api/create";

 $http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: url,
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: obj
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to be `x-www-form-urlencoded`? You would need to [serialise it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http) first. Otherwise it's enough to have `$http.post(url, obj)`

Comment: My C# Method</br>

[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/Create")]
public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody] Contact model)
{
    var c = new Contact();

    c.FName = model.FName;
    c.LName = model.LName;

    repository.Add(c);

return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

If I include x-www-form-urlencoded it inserts a record with blank fields.  If I disclude it, not record gets inserted.

Comment: edit your question to include C# code and add relevant tags

Comment: Solved     $http({
            method: 'POST',  url: url,  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},  data: $.param(dataObj)  });

Answer (score 0):

### URL-encoding variables using only AngularJS services

With AngularJS 1.4 and up, two services can handle the process of url-encoding data for POST requests, eliminating the need to manipulate the data with `transformRequest` or using external dependencies like jQuery:

1. [**`$httpParamSerializerJQLike`**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) - a serializer inspired by jQuery's [`.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)
2. [**`$httpParamSerializer`**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) - a serializer used by Angular itself for GET requests

**Example usage**

```
$http({
  url: 'some/api/endpoint',
  method: 'POST',
  data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.appForm.data), // Make sure to inject the service you choose to the controller
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // Note the appropriate header
  }
}).then(function(response) { /* do something here */ });
```