# How to POST content as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angularjs, api, angularjs-http

### angularjs $http.post is refusing to use my Content-Type

I am working with a contractor - their team are making server-side APIs while I'm putting together a javascript application using angularjs.  They insist on making the api only allow calls with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` calls, so I'm trying to figure out how to use $http to make a urlencoded call, and running into problems.  All the instruction pages I'm finding seem focused on older versions of angularjs.

I try using the below code:

```
$scope.makeApiCall = function(  ){
    var apiData = {
                    "key1" : "value1",
                    "key2" : "value2"
                };
    var apiConfig = {
                    "headers" : {
                        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;"
                    }
                };
    return $http.post('/Plugins/apiCall', apiData, apiConfig)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.data=response.data;
    });
};
```

But when I make the call, instead of using the Content-Type I provided, the developer tools report that it uses `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

How do I get my `$http.post` to send the right Content-Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to POST content as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Use the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service to transform the data:

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)
- [Stackoverflow -- URL-encoding variables using only AngularJS services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970229/5535245)

Comment: That does the trick, *thank* you.  I was hunting for something like that for *hours*.