# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in Spring Boot + Spring Security + CORS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cors

I'm trying CORS with Spring security. So here is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

And here is my WebMvcCofigurer :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
}
```

But it gives me 
**`from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`**

Current code :
**SecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .disable()//some stackoverflow solution(not accepted) said so
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

**I tried even a filter(As it crashes when starting, so I removed it)**
*MyCorsFilter.java*

```
@Configuration
public class MyCorsFilter {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");//tried list and all other collection stuff
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);//tried with negative value
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Also tried

```
http
.headers()
.addHeaderWriter(
      new StaticHeadersWriter(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "http://localhost:3000"))
```

And here is the `OAuth2` configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config {
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public GoogleOAuth2 google(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        Authentication authentication =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String accessToken = null;
        if (authentication.getClass()
                .isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
                    (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            String clientRegistrationId =
                    oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            if (clientRegistrationId.equals("google")) {
                OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                        clientRegistrationId, oauthToken.getName());
                accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            }
        }
        return new GoogleOAuth2(accessToken);
    }

}
```

Comment: which spring version are using ?

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud I'm using - 2.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 6):

Recently I faced the exact same error as I was trying to integrate my angular application to enable authentication for JWT based authentication using spring security.

I see what you are missing in your security configuration. Maybe that is the problem.

First of all, if you configure everything related to CORS in your security configuration then you don't need to create filter or extend WebMvcConfigurer.

Below is what you are missing in your security config.

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
```

Here is complete code I copied and pasted it from my working code which I fixed yesterday.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http  
            .cors()
            .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();

}
```

And then cors config code is which is almost same as yours.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    //the below three lines will add the relevant CORS response headers
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Remove your `MyCorsFilter` and `WebConfig` class. Both are not needed.

Comment: can you clear `jwtAuthEntityPoint` and `jwtFilter` ??

Comment: Simplified as you requested.

Comment: **`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=693417856482-slejtj57gb2nrcehe82ih45o2vdhkj5t.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=g9XON-I0coOhmke3n4wBAmMdhFQs1YgCq8ytPWWBVrU%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google&nonce=iDxik20BDhEDZ7xaNccu9pLZgAtsjYvZH2zGZ77UVQ0' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/token') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`**

Comment: Okay, I think I know where you are facing an issue now.  Google is blocking you to access this request from your localhost:3000. This URL should be open in a separate window.  Otherwise, it won't work.     It is better when you click on "Login with Google" button and you open separate child window and call  http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google  and let everythign happen in that child window.

Comment: It is not your app who is blocking this. It is Google, since when you request this URL from your domain localhost:3000. So during the request to google Origin was present. 

I hope this clarifies your concerns now.

Comment: Like I said when user clicks on 'Login with Google' button you need to open a separate child window and the URL of that child window should be http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google. Try this.

Comment: sorry to say, but that didn't worked.. again that [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvN8O.png) even inside popup window

Comment: Okay. Will try to replicate this at my local If I can. Meanwhile see if this helps you in any way. Complete code is there on github. https://medium.com/@mail2rajeevshukla/spring-security-5-3-oauth2-integration-with-facebook-along-with-form-based-login-767e10b02dbc

Comment: After adding this configuration.addAllowedHeader("*"); it works for me. My requirement is i need to allow specific urls and in my case its two this accepts only one string parameter. How do i acheive this?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

[CORS issue with Google Oauth2 for server side webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925165/cors-issue-with-google-oauth2-for-server-side-webapps)

[CORS issue while making an Ajax request for oauth2 access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276462/cors-issue-while-making-an-ajax-request-for-oauth2-access-token)

When you use the Authorization code grant (OAuth2 for backend apps - &response_type=code), you must redirect the browser to the /auth endpoint - you cannot use XHR for that. The user will be redirected back after authentication.

After redirecting to the /auth endpoint, user needs to see in an address bar that the page is from Google (trusted source) and Google may need to do some more redirects in order to authenticate the user and present the consent page. So using XHR is not possible.

---

You may use `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` with `CorsFilter` as used below. Please comment or remove the other CORS configurations and try with it.

```
package com.learning.jhipster.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(@Lazy CorsFilter corsFilter) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .disable()//some stackoverflow solution(not accepted) said so
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: It produces **`Error creating bean with name 'corsFilter': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`**

Comment: Hello @MaifeeUlAsad, Can you update the question with more detailed stacktrace

Comment: here is the complete stacktrace of now - https://pastebin.com/m2YUzyhE

please check and let me know

Comment: There might be a circular dependency, please add `@Lazy` as `SecurityConfig(@Lazy CorsFilter corsFilter)` and let me know

Comment: still network error, should i send you whole project ?

Comment: You may share the repository link, if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215015/discussion-between-patel-romil-and-maifee-ul-asad).

Comment: give me your github username

Comment: Username is romilptl

Comment: i have given you details in chat, you mentioned