# Spring Boot + React + Google OAuth2 CORS Error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, cors

**Background**: Have a react webapp on localhost:3000, spring boot backend on localhost:8080, and use OAuth2 from Google. The end goal is to log in through Oauth2 and retrieve said data from backend.

**Issue**: When I try perform a query I get the following error in console `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth...&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google`

**Attempted Approaches**: Disable CORS on spring (the config for it is below as what I currently have), change redirect URI to `http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect`, add some CORS filter from SO answers

**SO questions I have used for attempted approaches**: [CORS support in spring boot and security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219951/cors-support-in-spring-boot-and-security/60220073#60220073) (CORS Filter), [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in Spring Boot + Spring Security + CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038846/no-access-control-allow-origin-in-spring-boot-spring-security-cors) (disable CORS)

**Relevant Code**:
package.json (just proxy excerpt): `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`
App.js

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    clients: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('/cmds');
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState({clients: body});
  }

  render() {
    const {clients} = this.state;
    console.log(clients)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <div className="App-intro">
              <h2>Clients</h2>
              {clients.map(client =>
                  <div key={client.description}>
                    {client.description} ({client.global.toString()})
                  </div>
              )}
            </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

(Spring) application.yml (client ID and secret removed from question)

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
app:
  cors:
    allowedOrigins: http://localhost:3000,http://localhost:8080
  oauth2:
    authorizedRedirectUris:
      - http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
        security.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        security
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        //the below three lines will add the relevant CORS response headers
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot allow credentials and use the wildcard. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: @jub0bs I should've mentioned - tried that too (setting setAllowedOrigins to "http://localhost:3000"). Might be false train of thought but think it's more related to the fact that google auth doesn't sent back allowed CORS, not the backend

Comment: did you find a solution? I am facing similar problem.

Comment: @Ashish unfortunately not. I instead cut loses and rewrote the frontend in thymeleaf since the project was minimal enough.

Comment: Yeah, seems like that is the only solution which exists on the internet if you want to handle oauth2 client from the spring.