# PHP $_POST is empty, but HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA has all data

Tags: php, json, angularjs, post

I'm just trying to send a `POST` request with JS to server. But server has empty `$_POST` array. I could use `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, but it'll be deprecated in PHP 5.6. Could I have posted data in my `$_POST` array?

Environment: Chrome, apache2, PHP, AngularJS (I'm using `$http.post` function).

[Debug image](http://i.share.pho.to/c7e0e850_l.png) (sorry for not attaching image directly - I have no 10 reputation)

Comment: Try adding headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, to your $http.post?

Comment: See my [Debug image](http://i.share.pho.to/c7e0e850_l.png) for code. I tried `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` but in this case I have no neither `$_POST` nor `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` on server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The POST data must be in [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms) or [multipart/form-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Form_Data) format to get decoded properly. Your data seems to be JSON, so you have to decode it by yourself:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: Although, to exactly use it like $_POST we should add true as second parameter to json_decode so that it returns an array.
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your comment. Answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST` is populated by a request that is of type `form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Typically it looks like:

```
foo=bar&ipsum=lorm
```

So kinda like a `GET` request.

Since you're posting JSON directly (which is awesome!) you can use:

```
$request_payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) for more info.

Comment: Why is posting JSON directly awesome? (curiosity, no offense)

Comment: Because using form encoding on JSON data is problematic. Specifically empty values do not get transmitted. `{"foo":[],"bar:"baz"}` will result in just `bar=baz`. Form encoding has no way of specifying an empty array.

Comment: A missing empty array may not seem like a problem because you can add it as a default value. But, if you have: `{foo:[[],[]]}` form encoding gives an empty result. I think that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

See by default, jQuery transmits data using `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded` and the familiar `foo=bar&baz=moe` **serialization**. AngularJS, however, transmits data using `Content-Type: application/json` and `{ "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" }` **JSON serialization**, which unfortunately some Web server languages—notably PHP—do not unserialize natively.

so you can do this when you define your angular module:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [], function($httpProvider) {
    // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
});
```

answer taken from [this post by **Felipe Miosso**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276775/1059101).

Comment: Yeah, it's working. But I don't know, why direct setting 'Content-Type' in `$http.post(filtersUrl, data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})` is not working... I've did `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` and it's also working

Comment: `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` also does the same thing, but providing as suggested is available in the whole application i think.

Comment: And yes, in this case I was needed to do `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` on my server...

Answer (score 0):

looks like json data posting directly without any variable try with

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($request);
```

or use a variable on posting data like

```
data{'myvar': data}
```

and will get on POST data like

```
print_r($_POST['myvar']);
```

Comment: Both are not working:
1) `file_get_contents("php://input")` gives empty string;
2) `{'myvar': data}` has the same result as original post data (`$_POST` is empty)