# Angular Js $http.post method unable to access data in Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, zend-framework

This is my Angular js Function

```
 $scope.submitform = function () {
     $http.post('http://localhost:90/vendor/dashboard/accountinfosave/', 
        {'uname': 'vikrant', 'pswd': '111', 'email': 'bhallavikrantvir@gmail.com'}
                ).success(function(data) {
                    alert("success");

                }).error(function(data) { 
                    alert("error occured");

                });


  };
```

This is my Zend Framework Controller Function .

```
 public function accountinfosaveAction(){
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
       print_r($data);// not working 
       print_r($_POST);// not working  
}
```

The problem is I want to access the data(`uname,pswd,email`) I sent from Angular Js using `$http.post` function to zend framework .

If I use `$.ajax` function it works fine . But `$http.post` Does not work .
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to get post request 
 **$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");**

Comment: Worked for me print_r($postdata) Gives the post result .
Thanks .

Comment: yeah, I found another post that mentions angular encodes the data as json rather than what php expects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check post url is correct or not using test `echo` in `function` or a `contructor`

Try like this way,

```
var request = $http({
   method: "post",
   url: "http://localhost:90/vendor/dashboard/accountinfosave/",
   data: {
       uname : 'vikrant', 
       pswd  : '111', 
       email : 'bhallavikrantvir@gmail.com'
   }
});

request.success(
   function( data ) {
      $scope.data = data;
      alert('success');
   }
);
```

Comment: I have done echo as well . it is going to the zend function only i am not able to access the $_POST data there .