# AngularJS pass form array to php

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I am struggling to get this form to work was wondering if anyone can give me any ideas why! So what I have is an index page with an ng-app=especial. In the DIV main_area_holder goes the ng_view. The Ng-view displays fine and form displays on index page (from localtion app/partials/cust_form.php). What I am struggling to get working is the http request to php file so I can import form data into DB. I know the php code works without ajax (straight post request). If you can help out I would be very grateful.

**app.js UPDATED**

```
var especial = angular.module('especial', ['ngRoute']);

especial.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'custPage',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/cust_form.tpl.html'
    });
});

especial.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){
    if(typeof(request)!='object'){
        return request;
    }
    var str = [];
    for(var k in request){
        if(k.charAt(0)=='$'){
            delete request[k];
            continue;
        }
        var v='object'==typeof(request[k])?JSON.stringify(request[k]):request[k];
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return str.join("&");
};
$httpProvider.defaults.timeout=10000;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
});
especial.controller('custPage', function($scope, $http){
    $scope = {};
    $scope.custCreUpd = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'app/php/cust_cre_upd.php',
            data: $scope.cust,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data){

            console.log("OK", data)

        }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)})
    };
});
```

**cust_cre_upd.php**

```
<?php

        $post = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $values = json_decode($post, true);
        $table='customers';
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=displaytrends;charset=utf8', 'displaytrends', 'displaytrends');
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                    //Strip array to fields with values     
        $values=array_filter($values);
                    //Take array keys from array
        $field_keys=array_keys($values);
                    //Implode for insert fields
        $ins_fields=implode(",", $field_keys);
                    //Implode for insert value fields (values will binded later)
        $value_fields=":" . implode(", :", $field_keys);
                    //Create update fields for each array create value = 'value = :value'.
        $update_fields=array_keys($values);
        foreach($update_fields as &$val){
            $val=$val." = :".$val;
        }
        $update_fields=implode(", ", $update_fields);
                    //SQL Query
        $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ($ins_fields) VALUES ($value_fields) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_fields";
        $query = $conn->prepare($insert);
                    //Bind each value based on value coming in.
        foreach ($values as $key => &$value) {
            switch(gettype($value)) {
                case 'integer':
                case 'double':
                $query->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                break;
                default:
                $query->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }
        $query->execute();

    ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="especial">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Especial - Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
<img id="logo" src="images/especial-logo.jpg">
<a id="logout" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<div class="menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="sub_menu"></div>

<div class="main_area">
    <div id="main_area_holder" ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**cust_form.php**

```
<div ng-controller="custPage">
<div id="form">
        <form name="cust_form">   
           <label>Account No:</label>
           <input type="text" ng-model="cust.int_custID" name="cust[int_custID]" id="int_custID"/>
           <label>Company:</label>
           <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_company" name="cust[cust_company]" id="cust_company"/>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <textarea type="text" rows=5 ng-model="cust.cust_address" name="cust[cust_address]" id="cust_address"></textarea>
            <label>Postcode:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_postcode" name="cust[cust_postcode]" id="cust_postcode"/>
            <label>Contact 1:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_contact_1" name="cust[cust_contact_1]" id="cust_contact_1"/>
            <label>Contact 2:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_contact_2"  name="cust[cust_contact_2]"  id="cust_contact_2"/>
            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_tel" name="cust[cust_tel]" id="cust_tel"/>
            <label>Mobile:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_mob" name="cust[cust_mob]" id="cust_mob"/>
            <label>DDI:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_DDI" name="cust[cust_DDI]" id="cust_DDI"/>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" ng-model="cust.cust_email" name="cust[cust_email]" id="cust_email"/>
            <label>Notes:</label>
            <textarea type="text" rows=5 colums=1 ng-model="cust.cust_notes"  name="cust[cust_notes]" id="cust_notes"></textarea>

           <button type="submit" ng-click="custCreUpd()"> Submit </button>
       </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.js:

```
var especial = angular.module('especial', ['ngRoute']);

especial.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'custPage',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/cust_form.tpl.html'
    });
});

especial.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){
    if(typeof(request)!='object'){
        return request;
    }
    var str = [];
    for(var k in request){
        if(k.charAt(0)=='$'){
            delete request[k];
            continue;
        }
        var v='object'==typeof(request[k])?JSON.stringify(request[k]):request[k];
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return str.join("&");
};
$httpProvider.defaults.timeout=10000;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
});
especial.controller('custPage', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.cust = {};
   $scope.custCreUpd = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'app/php/cust_cre_upd.php',
        data: $scope.cust,
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    })
};
});
```

cust_cre_upd.php

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST); you can print_r it for understanding
//use $_POST as usual, example $_POST["cust_ID"] means your     
$values = $_POST;
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=displaytrends;charset=utf8', 'displaytrends', 'displaytrends');
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//Strip array to fields with values
$values=array_filter($values);
//Take array keys from array
$field_keys=array_keys($values);
//Implode for insert fields
$ins_fields=implode(",", $field_keys);
//Implode for insert value fields (values will binded later)
$value_fields=":" . implode(", :", $field_keys);
//Create update fields for each array create value = 'value = :value'.
$update_fields=array_keys($values);
foreach($update_fields as &$val){
    $val=$val." = :".$val;
}
$update_fields=implode(", ", $update_fields);
//SQL Query
$insert = "INSERT INTO $table ($ins_fields) VALUES ($value_fields) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_fields";
$query = $conn->prepare($insert);
//Bind each value based on value coming in.
foreach ($values as $key => &$value) {
    switch(gettype($value)) {
        case 'integer':
        case 'double':
            $query->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            break;
        default:
            $query->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
$query->execute();
```

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="especial">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Especial - Database</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">-->
    <script src="scripts/angular-1.3.8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <img id="logo" src="images/especial-logo.jpg">
    <a id="logout" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="sub_menu"></div>

<div class="main_area">
    <div id="main_area_holder" ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cust_form.php (cust_form.tpl.html):

```
<div id="form">
    <form name="cust_form">
        <label>Account No:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.int_custID" id="int_custID"/>
        <label>Company:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_company"  id="cust_company"/>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <textarea type="text" rows=5 ng-model="cust.cust_address" id="cust_address"></textarea>
        <label>Postcode:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_postcode" id="cust_postcode"/>
        <label>Contact 1:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_contact_1"  id="cust_contact_1"/>
        <label>Contact 2:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_contact_2"  id="cust_contact_2"/>
        <label>Telephone:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_tel" id="cust_tel"/>
        <label>Mobile:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_mob" id="cust_mob"/>
        <label>DDI:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cust.cust_DDI" id="cust_DDI"/>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="cust.cust_email" id="cust_email"/>
        <label>Notes:</label>
        <textarea type="text" rows=5 colums=1 ng-model="cust.cust_notes" id="cust_notes"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" ng-click="custCreUpd()"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I creat a repository here https://github.com/Danzeer/forJoshCrocker

To debug with script in web browser, you can use chrome's Developer's tools - network (option+command+i in OSX, F12 in window, and chose the network card).When you click submit, you can see request in network card and check http header by clicking the request.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Posting data now!!!! I was looking out at the debugging console and couldn't see anything which is why I asked if there should be changes... Thank again!!! :)

Comment: tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/devtools  and  detail https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Comment: Sorry didn't make that clear, I couldn't see changes but updated script now and all is working and can see the http header... :) Cheers,

Comment: open Develop tool before your clicking! I add two pic to be clear about debug; you can do it again  using your oldest script to find the difference of post's data. But the recent problem was the  ' $post = file_get_contents("php://input"); ' in cust_cre_upd.php. Since we have rewritten the httpProvider in angular js , we can get "custMob" value by using "$custMob = $_POST["custMod"]" in php . And  ' $post = file_get_contents("php://input"); ' will work without rewriting $httpProvider.

Comment: And the recent problem was exactly what you said - "The problem I have must be between either the post in app.js to PHP file or the decoding as it enters the PHP file"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find answer for "post" here [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

angualr's get works well, but angular's post does not seralize form-data as jquery.
my solution (maybe wrong, according to what I have searched) was rewriting angular's httpProvider:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){
        if(typeof(request)!='object'){
                return request;
        }
        var str = [];
        for(var k in request){
                if(k.charAt(0)=='$'){
                        delete request[k];
                        continue;
                }
                var v='object'==typeof(request[k])?JSON.stringify(request[k]):request[k];
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
        return str.join("&");
   };
   $httpProvider.defaults.timeout=10000;
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   };
  });
```

2 your

```
ng-click="custCreUpd"
```

should be

```
ng-click="custCreUpd()"
```

3 check  the result of below, I'm not familiar with it

$.param($scope.cust)

Comment: Thanks for help with the above, made the changes to the code but still no luck!!! Updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrite your code, that seems sending post. You can compare it with yours:

app.js :

```
var especial = angular.module('especial', ['ngRoute']);

especial.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'custPage',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/cust_form.tpl.html'
    });
});

especial.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){
    if(typeof(request)!='object'){
        return request;
    }
    var str = [];
    for(var k in request){
        if(k.charAt(0)=='$'){
            delete request[k];
            continue;
        }
        var v='object'==typeof(request[k])?JSON.stringify(request[k]):request[k];
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return str.join("&");
};
$httpProvider.defaults.timeout=10000;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
});
//when using 1.3.8 version , consider how to write controller with []
especial.controller('custPage', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.cust = {};
    //$scope = {}; !!!!
    $scope.custCreUpd = function(){ // pay attention of params
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "app/php/cust_cre_upd.php",
            data: $scope.cust,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data){

            console.log("OK", data)

        }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)})
    };
}]);
```

index.php:

```
!doctype html>
<html ng-app="especial">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Especial - Database</title>
<script src="js/angular-1.3.8.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
   <div id="main_area_holder" ng-view>
    </div>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

custForm.tpl.html(your cust_form.php):

```
<!--<div ng-controller="custPage"> !none ng-controller when using ng-route-->

<div id="form">
   <form name="cust_form">
       <label>Account No:</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="cust.int_custID" name="cust[int_custID]" id="int_custID"/>
       <button type="submit" ng-click="custCreUpd()"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

naming custForm.tpl.html instead of cust_form.php seems much meaningful) and request of .php will be pass to php executor by apache/nginx while request for html only through apache/nginx. And pay attention to angular cache problem when using ng-route. -- some tools not relavent  https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js and https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap, enjoy!

Points:
1 definition of controller

2 post of angularjs

3 how to use ng-view with ng-route

4 params-"$scope" of function custCreUpd hide $scope service

Comment: Hi man, used code above still not working at all. Is there something I am missing. This code all worked before angularjs and still can't get anything to post to PHP files now after 3 days with angular. There is nothing special I have to do to webserver to make this work is there?

Comment: Thanks for all this, I just thought I'd add some thought. Angularjs is working! If I use {{ cust }} on html form page it will echo in an array in the form {"int_custID":"test","cust_company":"test","cust_address":"test"} etc. This is good. The problem I have must be between either the post in app.js to PHP file or the decoding as it enters the PHP file. As I said I know the rest of the php code works provided it is given a php array. A couple other things, is the address bar meant to change on submit to something index.php#?xxxxx as currently it is not??? Thanks again...