# Not getting proper response from php using angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

**Requirement** - post data from angularJS controler to php file save data to database and give resonse to angularJS controller

**Issue** - I am posting some data from angularJS controller to php file and want response from there but having incorrect response like this

```
<?php $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); $fname =$data->firstName; $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => ''); $jsn = json_encode($arr); print_r($jsn); ?>
```

i.e the whole content of php file.

My controller function look like this -

```
app.controller('manageController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.addUser=function(user,event){
        var userJson=angular.toJson(user);  
           alert(userJson);     
        var responsePromise =$http({
                method: "post",
                url: "addUSer.php",
                data:userJson,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.fromServer = data;           
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Failed!");
        });
    }   
});
```

And php file look like this -

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $fname =$data->firstName;
     $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
?>
```

Browser giving error "no element found" in php file when i open it, its showing part before "$data->" in red color and remaining part in black color.

Can anyone give some suggestions on it.

Comment: did you try to hit addUSer.php in your browser? what do you get?

Comment: Have you given this a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122238/angularjs-pass-form-array-to-php

Comment: @yashhy after hitting it, its showing 

firstName; $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => ''); $jsn = json_encode($arr); print_r($jsn); ?>

Comment: Nope @TiagoMartins its too complicated and i am a beginner to angular JS

Comment: make sure your server is running properly and try to hit your php in rest client (which you can find as chrome extension). I doubt whether you php is compiled properly!

Comment: On your addUSer.php try "print_r($_POST); " to see what you're getting from angular.

Comment: ok i am trying your suggestion @yashhy

Comment: By the way, you're sure your webserver is running php, right?

Comment: nope thats why i am adding it now on xampp @TiagoMartins