# $_POST doesn't work well with $http POST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

in my controller.js I do like this

```
$http({
        url: 'http://example.com/api.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'YTParam' : 'test' }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
        }
    );
```

I even checked the network tool, the param did passed.

and in my api.php I try `echo $_POST["YTParam"]` but in my console I see nothing? What's wrong here? I tried to echo "string", it did appeared..

Comment: can you remove the quotes on YTParam

Comment: @yamidemichaos are u serious?

Comment: @yamidemichaos tried, but didn't worked..

Comment: This should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: @yamidemichaos Quotes makes no difference at all. Without it, JS knows the first occurence in an object couple is the key, and quotes it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not setting a header your server handles, try using this:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Comment: where I should put this?

Comment: Wherever you want in your php file, before you use $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not in the `$_POST` array, because your angular JS contentType is set to `application/json` by default, and PHP expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for a POST request. [Quoting from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
>
> Content-Type: application/json

To change this, either change this value in your config :

```
yourApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
}]);
```

Or at the time you send your request :

```
$http({
    url: 'http://myURL.com/api/',
    method: "POST",

    headers: {
     'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data: { 'YTParam' : 'test' }
})
```

You can set `contentType` directly as a property, but I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: @EltonJamie Please share that kind of information in your question in the first place.