# Laravel 4 - Mail function not working - returning a 500 error - MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: php, laravel-4, http-post, swiftmailer

I am having some trouble with Laravel 4's Mail function. What my application is doing is posting some user information to a route and that route is calling a function in the controller.

Post request (AngularJS):

```
$http.post('api/user/register', {username: username, email: email, password: password});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('api/user/register', 'UserController@registerUser');
```

Controller function (in UserController.php):

```
public function registerUser(){

        Mail::raw('TEST EMAIL', function($message) {
            $message->to('EmailOfUser', 'NameOfUser')->subject('Welcome!');
        });
}
```

While I was testing the registerUser() function, I would take the user information from the post request and put it into the database using DB::insert, and that worked perfectly. However, whenever I try to use the Mail::send or Mail::raw function it gives me a "MethodNotAllowedHttpException". After doing some research on this exception, it seemed like most people were making the mistake of using get on the route of a post request. As you can see above, I do not do that and I ams still having this problem. I have tested everything else, so I am certain that the Mail function is the issue. Please help, I have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Comment: Have you tried calling the route directly with something like PostMan or curl?

Comment: After using search, I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Comment: Ok I am going to try the post fix on angular, but I still do not think that is the issue. I posted this request using Postman and got the same error.

Comment: I found the error. It turns out that on the template I was passing through, there was a syntax error which was causing this issue. I fixed that and it is working just fine now. Thanks for the help!