# malformed JSON string Error while passing JSON from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, perl

I am trying to pass JSON string in ajax request. This is my code.

```
    NewOrder =  JSON.stringify (NewOrder);
    alert (NewOrder);

    var req = {
        url: '/cgi-bin/PlaceOrder.pl',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: "mydata="+ NewOrder
    };  

    $http(req)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert ('success');
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert (status);
        alert (data);
        alert ('Error')
    });
```

alert (NewOrder) gives -

```
{"ItemList":[{"ItemName":"Quality Plus Pure Besan 500 GM","Quantity":1,"MRP":"28.00","SellPrice":"25.00"}],"CustomerID":1,"DeliverySlot":2,"PaymentMode":1}
```

Which seems to be a valid JSON string.

But in script side I am getting following error. in this line

```
my $decdata = decode_json($cgi->param('mydata'));
```

malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")

Can please someone help me why i am getting this error?

Comment: Can you display on your server side `$cgi->param('mydata')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cgi->param('myData')` returns the query param string 'mydata', which in your case is not sent.

You're posting the json data in the request body of your http post payload, and not as a query/form param. In that case, you'd need some other function to read the contents of the request body in your server-side script.

which happens to be:

`my $data = $query->param('POSTDATA');`

as described in here: http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm#HANDLING_NON-URLENCODED_ARGUMENTS

Also you should remove the "mydata=" from your json in the body you post, because http request payload bodies do not have parameter names (they're for query/form-params only).

Your end code should be like this:

```
var req = {
    url: '/cgi-bin/PlaceOrder.pl',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: NewOrder
};
```

and the servers side:

```
my $decdata = decode_json($query->param('POSTDATA'));
```

Comment: Thanks neuro_sys. It works like a charm. I was struggling in this from couple of days. Your solution is just perfect. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to this issue: [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Usually I would post data like this:

```
var req = {
    url: '/cgi-bin/PlaceOrder.pl',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: {"mydata" : NewOrder}
};
```

However I am assuming that you are expecting the data as request params from this:

```
my $decdata = decode_json($cgi->param('mydata'));
```

If that is the case then the linked SO question is what you are looking for.

Comment: I changed the code as per your suggestion. But still same issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Angular $http.post accepts two params as url and payload

```
   var url = '/cgi-bin/PlaceOrder.pl';
   var payLoad = {'myData' :JSON.stringify(NewOrder)}; 

    $http.post(url, payLoad)
    .success(function(data) {
    console.log(success);
    })
```

At the server side, while fetching the required json string from the request param and then desearlize the json as following:

```
    $result = $cgi->param('myData');
    my $decdata = decode_json($result);
```

Comment: Hi Dev-One. I tried your suggestion. But i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the server side function on how you are handling the request of the json object i.e $cgi-> param('myData')

Comment: I am handling like this: 
my $decdata = decode_json($cgi->param('myData'));

Comment: Please be informed i am using Perl (not php), that's why using function decode_json (not json_decode)