# Ionic framework http post request

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post, ionic-framework

I want to send a `POST` request to a remote php file from an ionic app to save base64 encoded data in the database. When i pass `POST` data, I can see that the post parameter is sent, but when i print the response from the php file, it is blank.

I tried this code:

controller.js

```
$http.post("someurl", {data: {"data333": 'peter'}});
```

When I print `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` from php, it is a blank array, but from my console I can see that parameters are passed with the json `{data: {"data333": 'peter'}}`.

I have allowed cross domain in both client and server.

I also tried the standard ajax way:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'someurl/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, 
data : {"key": "value"}
})
```

Can anyone help me pass the data?

Comment: can you see whether the server receives the data? (via tcpdump/wireshark for example)

Comment: same question in ionic forums: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-framework-http-post-request/29195

Answer (score 6):

User object to pass the data to the server. Hope it is helping to you

```
myobject = { email: user.email,password:user.password };        
Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) 
{
  var p = [];
  for (var key in obj) 
  {
    p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
  }
  return p.join('&');
};

var req = 
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: "API-CALLING-URL",
    data: Object.toparams(myobject),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}

$http(req).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
    //success
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
    //error
});
```

Comment: this is also a nice solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload/14868725#14868725)

Comment: i glad it is help to you

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data?lq=1), this might be a problem between AngularJS using JSON and PHP expecting form data.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592352/1587329) is server-side / PHP:

> you can use:
>
> ```
> $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
> ```
>
> To access an array in PHP from an AngularJS POST.

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276775/1587329) tells you how to convert AngularJS data to a standard post request. It is lengthy. (JSON array to POST string etc)

Comment: its still same i cant capture the post data from server

Comment: @user3660436: If it's still not solved, you can try the edit.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't think I would be getting JSON instead of a standard POST request.

Answer (score 0):

The body needs to be uri encoded:

```
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'someurl/',
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, 
        data : {"key": "value"}
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $httpParamSerializer Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a while ago . Including these headers in PHP api saved my day.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

View details of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109876/unable-to-post-form-data-to-php-api-in-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work, ensure you define $httpParamSerializerJQLike in the controller and youre good to go,

```
   .controller('myCtrl', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: baseUrl,
   data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
    "user":{
    "email":"wahxxx@gmail.com",
    "password":"123456"
  }
  }),
     headers:
    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
```

})})