# req.body is null in expressjs server when sending post request from ionic app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app  when I am sending a post request using angularjs $http.post to my express js server, I cannot see the data in the req.body.

I am running my server on localhost:3000

Code in my server for CORS

```
     app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,DELETE,POST");
     next();
     });
```

My angular Js post request

```
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/signup',{"username":"x","password":"y"}).success(function(res){

     console.log(res);
     if(res.msg=="success")
     {
       //do something
     }
}
```

I am able to see data  in req.body  as "key" like:
`{'{"username":"x","password":"y"}':''}`
When I am setting the header from ionic app as:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-   urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

Please let me know how to debug this

Comment: are you using `body-parser` ? and if yes did you add `app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` ?

Comment: @georoot I have this in my app.js                               app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));                                   I also tried with                                                         app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) but got the same response

Comment: you mean to say that `req.body` in your case is empty ? if yes inspect the ajax request and post that over so we can see how exactly are the parameters posted to the server :)

Comment: @georoot this how my ajax request looks like

Comment: See this answer -- [SO: Url Encoding in AngularJS front end](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40963970/5535245)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured that out 
I have used this  stackoverflow link [Ionic framework http post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626872/ionic-framework-http-post-request) to parse my data before its send to my server

```
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
   Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj)
   {
     var p = [];
     for (var key in obj)
     {
       p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
     }
     return p.join('&');
   };

   $http({
     url: 'http://localhost:3000/signup',
     method: "POST",
     data: Object.toparams(u)
   })
     .then(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
       },
       function(response) { // optional
         // failed
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the entire data as key in `req.body`. This is because the angular request that you are making is wrong. Here is the part of code that should work

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/signup',
    method: "POST",
    data: { username : "a" , password : "b" }
})
.then(function(response) {
        // success
}, 
function(response) { // optional
        // failed
});
```

Comment: Thanks but my ajax request from client is going in this format after parsing Form Data  parsed
{"firstname":"a","lastname":"b","email":"abc@gmail.com","password":"12345678"}:       and I am receiving the same in body at express server

Comment: So what I think is I am not able to parse the form data correctly from my ionic app. Any suggestions what i can do to change it

Comment: Try passing data as `{ username : "a" , password : "b" }`

Comment: For give you more details Resposne Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,DELETE,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:19
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:78
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android