# Url Encoding in AngularJS front end with Spring REST backend

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, url, url-encoding

quick question. I have an AngularJS front end communicating with a Spring REST backend . URL encoding is only necessary for encoding parameters passed in the url (for application/x-www-form-urlencoded). I don't have to worry about the encoding in the body, correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the body of a post message needs to be uri encoded:

```
$http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

OR alternately:

```
var config = {
    transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};

$http.post(myUrl, myData, config);
```

For more information, see:

- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializer Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)
- [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: I thought it was only the url where parameters are passed that have to concern themselves with this

Comment: If the POST method is used with content type `application/json` the AngularJS framework will automatically encode it as JSON. If the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the body needs to be uri encoded.