# How to pass data from angularJs to asp net mvc controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

How to pass data from angularjs to asp net mvc controller method?

Tried the technique from [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="targetApp">
<head>
<title>Targets</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/b..">
</head>
<body ng-controller="targetController">
<div class="page-header">
<h1> Список дел на сегодня</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8">
<input class="form-control" ng-model="target" placeholder="Цель" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="priority" placeholder="Приоритет" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem(target, priority)">Добавить</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="save('123')">Сохранить</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Цель</th>
<th>Приоритет</th>
<th>Сделано</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in list.items">
<td>{{item.target}}</td>
<td>{{item.priority}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1.."></script>
<script>
var model = {
items: [
{ target: "Попробовать angular.js", priority: 1, done: false },
{ target: "Съесть бизнес-ланч", priority: 2, done: true }
]
};
var targetApp = angular.module("targetApp", []);
targetApp.controller("targetController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.list = model;
$scope.addItem = function (target, priority) {
$scope.list.items.push({ target: target, priority: priority, done: false });
};

// Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$scope.save = function (target) {
$http.post('/DayActivity/testPost', $scope.list.items[0]).success(function (answ) {
});
};

/**
* The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
* Ольга Штамм {Object} obj
* Артём Зайцев {String}
*/
var param = function (obj) {
var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
for (name in obj) {
value = obj[name];
if (value instanceof Array) {
for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
subValue = value[i];
fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
innerObj = {};
innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
query += param(innerObj) + '&';
}
}
else if (value instanceof Object) {
for (subName in value) {
subValue = value[subName];
fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
innerObj = {};
innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
query += param(innerObj) + '&';
}
}
else if (value !== undefined && value !== null)
query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
}
return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
};

// Override $http service's default transformRequest
$http.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
}];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code of the mvc controller:

```
public class DayActivityController : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult testPost(JsonResult j)
{
return null;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, the data  JsonResult.Data is null.
How to pass the data from angularks to the asp net mvc controller method?

Comment: Please format your post and code. This is really hard to understand.

Comment: can you please try `object` instead of `JsonResult`?

Comment: Sorry guys. Tried to format. Hope this time the code is better to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `ApiController` version. Maybe it can help.

`transformRequest` is the main hint to chase:

```
logError: function (action, context, type, message) {
    var resourceUri = 'log/dosomething/';
    var jsonObject = { "Action": action,"Message": message,"Context":context };

    var logQuery = $resource(resourceUri, {} , {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var result = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }).save();
}

public class LogController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("DoSomething")]
    public void DoSomething([FromBody]MyObject myObj)
    { }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
}
```