# How to get POST data from angular ajax with php

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I'm having trouble retrieving or sending data with POST using PHP and angular. I reduced my problem to the easiest case but still the response is an empty array.

Here is my Angular code:

```
this.search = function() {
    console.log("searching");
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'search/',
        data: {search:1, direct: true}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error retrieving data.");
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

and my PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($_POST) ;

?>
```

The funny thing is that using GET in both places, it works :/

Comment: Most likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular serializes js objects into JSON to POST, php does not populate the $_POST data structure from a JSON post body, to ge the json data in the post body you'll have to read from `php://input`

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo file_get_contents('php://input') ;

?>
```

Comment: Why does angular send your js object as json? maybe because json is sexier than urlencoded form data(just a guess). Unless you send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` you can't use $_POST, (except if you do `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);`). I'm no angular expert but there are ways to get the data to send as form data and use $_POST, I do however think that any performance gain or loss will be negligible.

Comment: and how do you convert that to an array? I've tryed with `json_decode`, but something weird happens...

Comment: Did you set the second parameter of json_decode to true