# $http.post not sending variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Am I doing something wrong? When I do the following I receive no post variables in `/url`

```
$http.post("/url", { something: "something" })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data){ alert("An error occurred. Please try again."); }
);
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for this @Fiete - Learn something new everyday

Answer (score 0):

By default angular encodes data to `Content-Type: application/json` but you want it to be `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded`. The later is set to default by `jQuery post`, thats why most of the newcomers fall into that trap.

So you have to set the content type before you do the request.

```
yourApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
}]);
```

Now before every http request, the content type is changed to what we set above.

Same topic is been discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues related to HTTP headers, the below works fine with me in all cases.

```
var data = {something: "something"};
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
//Uncomment this if the problem persists, it's to explicitly state the content type.
    //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```