# Laravel 5.2 API Rest and Angular JS - $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel-5

I am trying to send an $http.post AJAX data to a route configured in Laravel 5.2, everything works perfect, but the server returns this error:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
>   Unknown on line 0

This is my code. PHP:

```
public function save(Request $request){
      $input = $request->all();
      try {
        $direccion = urlencode($input['Calle']." ".$input['Numero'].", ".$input['Ciudad']);

        $geocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$direccion&key=APIKEY";
        $datosGoogle = json_decode($this->curl($geocode), true);

        $latitud = $datosGoogle['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $longitud = $datosGoogle['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

        if(is_double($latitud) && is_double($latitud)){
          $input['Latitud'] = $latitud;
          $input['Longitud'] = $longitud;
          $new = MyModel::create($input);
          $data = ["status"=>"ok", "message"=>"Agregado correctamente"];
        }else{
          $data = ["status"=>"fail", "message"=>"Dirección desconocida, compruebe que los datos son correctos para que podamos agregarla al sistema."];
        }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data = ["status"=>"error", "message"=>$e->getMessage()];
      }
      return response()->JSON($data);
    }
```

JS:

```
$scope.registrar = function(form, datos) {
      $scope.submitted = true;
      if(form.$valid) {
        var toSendData = JSON.stringify({
          Nombre: datos.nombre,
          Calle: datos.calle,
          Numero: datos.numero,
          Piso: datos.piso,
          Puerta: datos.puerta,
          CP: datos.cp,
          Ciudad: datos.ciudad,
          Email: datos.email,
          Necesidades: datos.necesidades,
          Telefono: datos.telefono
        });
        console.log(toSendData);
        $http.post($rootScope.recibirNuevoUrl, toSendData).then(function(response){
          $scope.hideLoading();
          if(response.data.status == "ok"){
            $state.go('registro');
          }else{
            $scope.$parent.showAlert("Error al introducir los datos", response.data.message);
          }
        })
      }else{
        $scope.$parent.showAlert('Validacion de datos', 'El formulario contiene errores. Por favor revise los campos marcados para comprobar los errores.');
      }
    };
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Laravel 5.2 and Angular, I got it working by adding a single line in my controller:

```
editorApp.controller('EditorCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $interval, $document){

    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    ...
```

I found this working for me in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254137/4021927. The answer marked as correct did not work for me, the line above is from an other answer in the same post. The correct answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276775/4021927) does tell you why you need it though.

In short why this problem exist is because Angular (By default) send data using JSON serialization: `Content-Type: application/json` and PHP does not unserialize JSON natively. By changing content-type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` the data will be sent as:

```
foo=bar&bar=foo
```

instead of (JSON):

```
{ "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo" }
```

Comment: You rules!!! I had review thousand of posts and webs for this solution. Can you explain a bit your solution (thinking of new people who arrives here with the same problem) ? A million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem retrieving $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] in Laravel 5.2. I solved the issue by using `Request::getContent()` in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Got mine working after turning off error_reporting in php.ini

1. Open php.ini
2. Search for error_reporting
3. Change it to => error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
4. Exit and Start / Restart apache server
5. Restart laravel server

Comment: That is not a solution, you are only hiding the real problem.

Comment: You are right, but when the recommended solution does not work and you have deadlines to meet this can help you get your app working while you keep searching for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

laravel 5.2

/resource/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```js
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
//add default Content-Type 
window.axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

**2 data mast be string**

```js
const qs = require('qs')
axios.post('/api/code/create', qs.stringify(this.formItem),)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```